# Returning a reference to an object constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, reference, scope

Take a look at this code:

```
Foo &Bar::Copy()
{
    return Bar();
}
```

The class Bar is inherited from Foo, and Foo is an abstract class. But when I call `Bar()` and return it, is it safe to do so? Or would I be returning the address of a local variable that would be freed by the end of the `Copy()` function?

Advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Returning reference to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)

Comment: @GWW - No it isn't. I didn't know if returning a constructor counted as returning a local allocation or not. It will probably be beneficial to anyone else confused about the same thing.

Comment: Actually this shouldn't even compile because an rvalue is bound to a non-const reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `Bar();` you call constructor on an implicit temporary object to which reference is returned. If you intend to create a `Clone()` like function a typical solution is to create the clone on the heap with `new`. You may use a kind of smart pointer to simplify life cycle management. You may also apply covariant return type to avoid type conversions in some cases using signature: `Bar &Bar::Copy()`

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning a ctor. `Bar();` *invokes* the ctor, creating a temporary object. You're then returning a reference to that temporary object.

Since a ctor in C++ doesn't have a name, you can't do many of the usual things you could on normal functions, such as getting/returning a pointer to a function. It's no entirely clear what you're really trying to accomplish here, but if you want to return something that will construct an object, you usually need to define a static member function that invokes the ctor, and return a pointer to that static member function.

Comment: Well in the long run I'm trying to create an array of `Foo*` pointers (in theory, its not called Foo in my real program). I was worried that the lifetimes of the pointers being inserted into it would make it prone to undefined behavior, so I was trying to insert copies so the lifetimes of the addresses would cohere with the array. I suppose using a smart pointer and allocating on the heap would be best for this though, as jszpilewski has mentioned.

Comment: @AutoBotAM: You might also want to look at Boost [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Comment: The pointer container library over all looks like what I need. Will try.

Answer (score 0):

This is an undefined behaviour, because temporary `Bar` object will be destroyed at `;`.

```
Foo Bar::Copy()
{
    return Bar();
}
```

is safer. BUT thanks to @Cat Plus Plus and @celtschk, I realized that this method leads to slicing, losing the all `Bar` specific information. In order to keep the `Bar` object `Copy()` must return either a reference or a pointer to the object. Here we are at the beginning again as this is UB. So `Bar`must be allocated dynamically instead, that its reference/pointer lives at the out of `Copy()` function. Who should be responsible for deleting this dynamically generated `Bar` object?

```
#include <memory>
std::shared_ptr<Foo> Bar::Copy()
{
    return std::shared_ptr(new Bar());
}
```

`shared_ptr` will do this automatically for you.

Comment: The second snippet slices the object.

Comment: The first snippet slices the object as well.