# Matrix triangularization cause error wrong type argument to unary minus

Tags: c, matrix

I have this method that returns a value used in matrix triangularization routine

```
 float **trian(int n, float **Xy)
    {
        int i,row,col;
        float **sign = 1;
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int max = 0;

            for ( row = i; row < n; row++)
                if (fabs(Xy[row][i]) > fabs(Xy[max][i]))
                    max = row;

            if (max) {
                sign = -sign;
                float *tmp = Xy[i];
                Xy[i] = Xy[max], Xy[max] = tmp;
            }

            if (!Xy[i][i]) return 0;
            row=0;
            for (row = i + 1; row < n; row++) {
                float r = Xy[row][i] / Xy[i][i];
                if (!r) continue;

                for ( col = i; col < n; col ++)
                    Xy[row][col] -= Xy[i][col] * r;
            }
        }
        return sign;
    }
```

Unfortunately get this error

```
main.c:74:20: error: wrong type argument to unary minus
```

the line of the error

```
 sign = -sign;
```

Comment: can you please mark the line in the snippet?

Comment: I suspect that here is already an error `float **sign = 1;` why does the compiler not complain?

Comment: Why has it to be C? Speed? ;) ...seems you never used C before.

Comment: As to return a pointer to a pointer to a float you have to use more variables, but these must not be local. Did you try to solve the problem in Java?

Comment: Does [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23744291/2932052) work as expected? Then it's only a porting problem. But: Why then **this** new question? Why not: "how to return an 2D array in C?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's something wrong here:

```
float **sign = 1;
....
sign = -sign;
```

did you mean to use `**sign` instead of `sign`?

---

perhaps you need just something like this:

```
int trian(int n, float **Xy) {
  ...
  int sign = 1;
  ...
  sign = -sign;
  ...
  return sign;
}
```

Comment: yes the error is at this line, but if I write `float **sign = 1;` get `incompatible types error`. a way tofix this?

Comment: Is correct if I  change `float **sign = 1` in `float sign = 1` and `return sign;` in `return **sign;`?

Comment: @AndreaF no. absolutely not. Better try another language. Python could be your friend.

Comment: @Wolf
I need C now not python. I have always used Java I'm new to C language. I need to calc sign and return the reference to sign value.

Comment: so what exactly is `sign` supposed to be? a `float`? or a matrix? or is it just `-1`/`1` and you can go with `int`?

Comment: @AndreaF why do you return a reference to sign?

Comment: @Pavel It's a value not a matrix, yes I should go also with int

Comment: @wolf Is there a precise reason why I have to return the value and not the reference?

Comment: @AndreaF you may not return a reference to a local variable, because otherwise you cause undefined behaviour (wrong values, crashes) when accessing the reference after the function has returned. Values are fine, they are copied to the caller (who holds the memory for it).