# How to pass up a struct edit[how to store lines]

Tags: c, sockets

```
this output

Andrew Tanenbaum, David Wetherall
    Computer Networks
    Michaell Donahoo, Kenneth Calvert
    TCP/IP Sockets in C
    William,Stallings
    Yale Patt, Sanjay Patel

is the result of this code.




#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket() and bind() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include "./book.h"
#ifndef fileget_C
#define fileget_C
#endif // fileget_C

 void readlib(Book* Library){
/*char stock[4][125];*/
  FILE *bookfile=fopen("/home/ninja/Sockets/bookstock.txt","r+");


  size_t len=0;
  int num;
  ssize_t read;
  char *stringin;
  char *isbn;
  int *numin;

int n;
  for(n=0; n<4; n=n+1){
  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  strncpy(Library[n].isbn,stringin,strlen(stringin));
  //printf("%s",Library[n].isbn);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  strncpy(Library[n].Author,stringin,strlen(stringin));
  //printf("%s",Library[n].Author);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  strncpy(Library[n].title,stringin,strlen(stringin));
  //printf("%s",Library[n].title);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  num=atoi(stringin);
  Library[n].edition=num;
  //printf("%d\n",Library[n].edition);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  Library[n].year=atoi(stringin);
  stringin=NULL;
  //printf("%d\n",Library[n].year);

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  strncpy(Library[n].publisher,stringin,strlen(stringin));
  stringin=NULL;


  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  Library[n].inventory=atoi(stringin);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  Library[n].available=atoi(stringin);
  //printf("%d\n",Library[n].available);

  }
 // printf("%s",Library[0].title);
  //printf("%s",Library[1].title);
  //printf("%s",Library[2].title);
  //printf("%s\n",Library[3].title);

  printf("%s",Library[0].Author);
  printf("%s",Library[1].Author);
  printf("%s",Library[2].Author);
  printf("%s",Library[3].Author);



}
```

For some reason, I'm getting extra lines stored or I am not storing to the pointer in an appropriate way. The commented out print lines in the for loop display the right information which includes printing the appropriate author field of the struct.

Comment: The error message says you're returning a pointer to a local variable. It's odd that the compiler isn't objecting to the implicit return type is `int` since you don't show any return type. You could use `malloc()` or one of its relatives to allocate an array of structures and return the pointer to that:  `Book *readlib(const char *filename)` would be a signature (don't hard code the file name either). Or the caller can pass an array of structures to the function: `size_t readlib(const char *filename, Book *library, size_t libsize)` (`libsize` is the array size; return the number of books).

Comment: BTW: `strncpy(Library[n].isbn,stringin,strlen(stringin));` is wrong. (using strncpy() is almost always wrong)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `readlib()` and your `Library`.

Note that the `return` of the `readlib()` is not of type `Book*`, while you return `Library` which is of type `Book[]`, thus the compiler gives you the warning.

Also, it seems like you are trying to `return` an `array` in C. [Be very careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c). Technically, you could change the `return` of `readlib()` like this:

```
Book* readlib()
```

But it is highly not recommended. It is better to have array declared outside of the function and the function contains the `Book*` argument in it:

```
void readlib(Book* Library, int noOfBook)
```

Then you declare your

```
Book Library[4]; //somewhere else
```

and call the `readlib` like this:

```
readlib(Library, 4);
```

You do not need to to:

```
return Library;
```

In the `readlib`, since it is already declared outside and passed to the `readlib`

Of course, if you really want to `return` `Book*` however, you could prepare proper memory space by using `malloc` in the function:

```
Book* readlib(int noOfBook){
    Book *Library = malloc (noOfBook * sizeof(Book));
    //something else
    return Library;
}
```

But I personally prefer to handle all these outside.

Comment: You could also declare `Book * readlib()` and dynamically allocate `Library` (e.g. `Book *Library = malloc (4 * sizeof *Library);`) and then return a pointer to `Library` (e.g. `return Library;`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ah, yes. using `malloc`, that will be a lot more proper if we want to return `Book*`

Comment: Either way is fine - e.g. pass `Book *Library` as a parameter or dynamically allocate. It all depends if you need to grow `Library` later with `realloc`. If not, passing it as a parameter (along with its max size) is probably more efficient `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah. `:)` perhaps, I am more towards the parameter passing option together with its `maxSize`. Not sure if this is considered old-fashioned? :)

Comment: No, it's not old fashioned at all. Statically allocated storage provides faster access and does not require the function call overhead that `malloc`/`calloc`/`free` does. It's is a trade off. If you know you `max` size before hand, the static passing is a better option. If you don't, then you need to dynamically allocate and keep track of the allocation size and `realloc` as required. Just a matter of tailoring the code to the particular problem at hand.

Comment: If I were to pass down the reference to library as a pointer in arguments, would it create a new instance or would it  being modifying the instance of the array in the c file that called to it.

Comment: @Mike it will create new pointer, *but* the new pointer will point to the *same* instance as the pointer in the caller file. Thus, you do *not* create new instance of *Book*, You create new *pointer* which point to the same *Book* instances.