# All returning values of array are 0

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Yesterday I asked for a help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840003/how-to-return-an-array-from-function-to-main) question, and now the situation is better, but not OK. I repost the correct code, but it returns another problem, despite the corrections. The second function reads all the array's values as 0.
I think the problem is about the pointers, but I can't understand how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int leggiSequenza(char *nomeFile, int *seq) {

    FILE *in;
    int i;
    int dim;

    if((in = fopen(nomeFile, "r"))==NULL) {
        printf("Errore: impossibile leggere il fie in apertura.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fscanf(in, "%d", &(dim));
    printf("Trovati %d valori.\n", dim);

    if(dim < 0) {
        printf("Errore: il numero di interi risulta negativo.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    seq = (int*) malloc(dim*sizeof(int));

    i=0;
    while(!feof(in) && i<(dim)) {
        fscanf(in, "%d", &seq[i]);
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<(dim); i++) {
        printf("Il valore letto in posizione %d è: %d.\n", i+1, seq[i]);
    }


    fclose(in);
    free(seq);

    return dim;
    }




int numeroPassi(int *valori, int size) {

    int i;
    int somma;
    int passi[size];

    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("valore in posizione %d = %d.\n", i+1, valori[i]);
    }

    somma=0;
    for(i=0; i<(size-1); i++) {
        somma = somma + abs(valori[i]);
    }

    printf("La somma del valore assoluto di tutti gli elementi è: %d.\n", somma);

    return 0;
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char nomeFile[200];
    int passi;

    printf("\n");

    printf("Inserire il nome del file:\n");
    scanf("%s", nomeFile);
    printf("\n");

    int * p = malloc(200*sizeof(int));
    int dim = leggiSequenza(nomeFile, p);
    printf("dimensione = %d\n", dim);
    printf("\n");

    passi = numeroPassi(p, dim);

    printf("\n");

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit your code and indent it properly, if you expect anyone to read this question.

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you would use the english language in your code.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I forgot to change language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not writing to the array you passed in to `leggiSequenza`. Instead you are allocating a new array that you write to and then free.

Remove the following lines from `leggiSequenza` to fix that problem:

```
seq = (int*) malloc(dim*sizeof(int));
```

and

```
free(seq);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int * p = malloc(200*sizeof(int));
```

Ok, here you allocated some memory. Now you pass that pointer `p` into first function:

`int dim = leggiSequenza(nomeFile, p);`

Inside this function you have a variable `seq` that is a pointer actually pointing to the same memory that `p` does.

Let's look further: `seq = (int*) malloc(dim*sizeof(int));`
Here you allocated new memory and afterwards do something with it.

Then you call `free(seq)` thus the memory allocated by second call to `malloc` is cleared (memory pointed to by `p` is still valid but remains unchanged)

Now you call `passi = numeroPassi(p, dim);`. Here memory pointed to by `p` is used as if there was no changes by first function

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand where's the error. Very kind.

Comment: @FranzGoogle - Be mindful of what you understood. It's only now a correct answer.