# Difficulty printing char pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers

I've been struggling on this problem all day now, and looking at similar examples hasn't gotten me too far, so I'm hoping you can help! I'm working on the programming assignment 1 at the end of CH 3 of Operating Systems Concepts if anyone wanted to know the context.

So the problem is to essentially create a command prompt in c that allows users to input a command, fork and execute it, and save the command in history. The user can enter the command 'history' to see the 10 most recent commands printed out. The book instructed me to store the current command as a char pointer array of arguments, and I would execute the current one using `execvp(args[0], args)`. My professor added other requirements to this, so having each argument individually accessible like this will be useful for those parts as well.

I decided to store the history of commands in a similar fashion using an array of char pointers. So for example if the first command was `ls -la` and the second command entered was `cd..` we would have `history[0] = "ls -la"` and `history[1] = "cd.."`. I'm really struggling getting this to work, and I'm fairly certain I'm screwing up pointers somewhere, but I just can't figure it out.

In main I can print the first word in the first command (so just `ls` for `ls -la`) using `arg_history[0]` but really can't figure out printing the whole thing. But I know the data's there and I verify it when I add it in (via `add_history` function) and it's correct! Even worse when I pass it to the `get_history` function made for printing the history, it prints a bunch of gibberish. I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding why it's doing this! Right now I have a hunch it's something to do with passing pointers incorrectly between functions, but based on what I've been looking at I can't spot the problem!

```
/**
 * Simple shell interface program.
 *
 * Operating System Concepts - Ninth Edition
 * Copyright John Wiley & Sons - 2013
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



#define MAX_LINE        80 /* 80 chars per line, per command */
#define HIST_LENGTH     10

void get_input(char *args[], int *num_args, char *history[], int *hist_index);
void get_history(char *history[], int hist_index);
void add_history(char *history[], char *added_command, int *hist_index);

int main(void)
{
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1]; /* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */
    char *arg_history[HIST_LENGTH];

    int num_args;
    int hist_index;

    int should_run = 1;
    int i;

    while (should_run){   
        printf("osh>");
        fflush(stdout);

        get_input(args, &num_args, arg_history, &hist_index);

        //printf("%s\n", arg_history[0]); //incorrectly prints up to the first space
        //printf("%s\n", args[0]) //prints the correct arg from the last command (eg. for 'ls -la' it prints ls for args[0] and -la for args[1])

        if (strcmp(args[0], "history") == 0) {
            get_history(arg_history, hist_index);
        }        
    }

    return 0;
}

void get_input(char *args[], int *num_args, char *history[], int *hist_index) {
    char input[MAX_LINE];
    char *arg;

    fgets(input, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = NULL; // To remove new line character - the compiler doesn't like how I'm doing this

    add_history(history, input, hist_index);

    arg = strtok(input, " ");

    *num_args = 0;
    while(arg != NULL) {
        args[*num_args] = arg;
        *num_args = *num_args + 1;
        arg = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

void get_history(char *history[], int hist_index) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < HIST_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%d %s\n",  hist_index, *history);
        // prints gibberish
        hist_index = hist_index - 1;
        if (hist_index < 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void add_history(char *history[], char *added_command, int *hist_index) {
    int i;
    for (i = HIST_LENGTH-1; i > 0; i--) {
            history[i] = history[i-1];
    }

    history[0] = added_command;
    *hist_index = *hist_index + 1;
    //printf("%s\n", history[0]); prints correctly
}
```

---

Update:
I made the changes suggested by some of the solutions including moving the pointer to `input` out of the function (I put it in main) and using `strcpy` for the `add_history` function. The reason I was having an issue using this earlier was because I'm rotating the items 'up' through the array, but I was accessing uninitialized locations before history was full with all 10 elements. While I was now able to print the `arg_history[0]` from main, I was still having problems printing anything else (eg. arg_history[1]). But more importantly, I couldn't print from the `get_history`function which is what I actually needed to solve. After closer inspection I realized `hist_index` is never given a value before it's used to access the array. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: i guess strtok(input, " ") broke your input line. you may try to print out input before strtok() and after strtok() to see what you got.

Comment: After calling `get_input` if you print out args[] in main it functions correctly. The issue is accessing the data in arg_history

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> input[strlen(input) - 1] = NULL; // To remove new line character - the compiler doesn't like how I'm doing this
> ```

Of course it doesn't. There are many things wrong with this. Imagine if `strlen(input)` is 0, for example, then `strlen(input) - 1` is -1, and you're accessing the -1th item of the array... not to mention `NULL` is a pointer, *not* a character value. You probably meant `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';`, but a safer solution would be:

```
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

```
history[0] = added_command;
*hist_index = *hist_index + 1;
//printf("%s\n", history[0]); prints correctly
```

This prints correctly because the pointer value `added_command`, which you assign to `history[0]` and which points into `input` in `get_command` is still alive. Once `get_command` returns, the object that pointer points to no longer exists, and so the `history[0]` pointer also doesn't exist.

You should know you need to use `strcpy` to assign strings by now, if you're reading a book (such as K&R2E). Before you do that, you need to create a new object of suitable size (e.g. using `malloc`)...

This is a common problem for people who aren't reading a book... Which book are you reading?

---

```
    printf("%d %s\n",  hist_index, *history);
    // prints gibberish
```

Well, yes, it prints gibberish because the object that `*history` once pointed to, before `get_command` returned, was destroyed when `get_command` returned. A book would teach you this.

See also [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c) for a similar explanation...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That first section was very useful, I need to learn to read my compiler better. I knew I was something along those lines but I didn't quite understand.

For the second half I'm following your train of thought, but I'm a bit skeptical that once `get_command` returns the pointer is gone, because the print statement following where it returns prints the entire string up to the space. If there's no space it'll print the entirety of which ever command in history I point it to. If there is a space it'll point up to that.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask another question about the warning message, such as "What does ... mean?" or "How do I decipher ...?", filling in the blanks with a part you don't understand...

Comment: Regarding your skepticism, consider that the pointer points into stack space... until you call another function (to reuse the stack space), that stack space won't be overwritten. Once the stack space is overwritten, this is where the garbage comes from. This is technically *undefined behaviour*, something to be avoided.

Comment: I'm going to move the input pointer out of the function and into main, but I'm still not sure you're 100% correct. And there's no need to be condescending, in an earlier unsuccessful version I was using `srtcpy`, but as I said I've been working on this all day so it's gone though some changes. Thank you for pointing that out though. I'm reading the book I mentioned in the original post, and have read other C books in the past, but I am very rusty.

Comment: Well regarding the error you cleared it up for me. I didn't realize `NULL` was a pointer, which now makes sense what the compiler meant referring to it as `void *`. You helped me and cleared it up; I don't see what the point of helping is if you're going to be rude about it.

Comment: @PhilBaldoni SO is a place for learning; please avoid jumping to the conclusion that people are being rude. It may seem offensive to point out that students who read the right selection of books usually don't have this problem; feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, as I assume that's what you've taken offense to... but I'm merely pointing out statistics, and making an inference (that you need a better book) from that. This is often a natural gift to programmers. There's no need to take offence to that. It's not a judgment on you as a person, but a suggestion to select a better book.

Comment: Which is exactly what I'm here for. I was having issues with my code, and I asked a question so I could learn about and understand why it wasn't working - which is what I did. I wasn't here just asking for someone to fix it - as so many others do. I'm actually trying to _learn_. I made it very clear which book I am reading, and I also made it very clear that I am weak with pointers. I find it quite ironic you're telling me not to jump to conclusions about you being rude (which I still stand by), meanwhile you're jumping to conclusions that I'm not reading.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a book about C. You could've said "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", and this would be equally relevant. I'm not the only one recommending K&R2E to people, and it wouldn't be disrespectful of me to assume that you're capable of reading, that book in particular. I used to frequent Freenode and EFnets C-related channels, and have also heard praise regarding the other names mentioned there, so if K&R doesn't seem to work for you, there are alternatives...

Comment: Sorry I got busy and forgot to follow up, but thank you for the help and book suggestion. I've since picked up a copy of K&R2E and its been quite useful and a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some description of strtok(). Because you just put the pointer of input to your history list instead of putting a copy, you'd only print out the first word.

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
Parameters
str -- The contents of this string are modified and broken into smaller strings (tokens).

delim -- This is the C string containing the delimiters. These may vary from one call to another.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I agree I need to copy the copy a new pointer instead of the one directly from input, but I'm confused how `strtok` impacts this? I only use `strtok` on `arg[]` after it's already put in the history list.

Comment: @PhilBaldoni you need to copy the whole text of input, not just the pointer itself. what you put in history is just the address of the starting point of the input text. but you passed the same address to strtok which broke up the text at that address (namely,  putting '\0' at spaces between words), so when you tried print out the text at the saved address, you just got the first word. one way to solve the issue, is to add char copy[MAX_LINE]; then do strcpy(copy, input); after you got the input, then do arg = strtok(copy, " "); instead of arg = strtok(input, " ");