# Pass str as an int array to a Python C extended function (extended using SWIG)

Tags: python, arrays, c, ctypes, swig

How can I pass a `str` value (containing 3000 {'0', '1'} bytes) obtained using python code as an argument to a python c extended function (extended using SWIG) which requires `int *` (fixed length int array) as an input argument? My code is such:

```
int *exposekey(int *bits) {
    int a[1000];
    for (int j=2000; j < 3000; j++) {
        a[j - 2000] = bits[j];
    }
    return a;
}
```

What I've tried was to use `ctypes` (see below code):

```
import ctypes
ldpc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./_ldpc.so')
arr = (ctypes.c_int * 3072)(<mentioned below>)
ldpc.exposekey(arr)
```

with 3072 {0, 1} entered in the  position. Python returns syntax error : more than 255  arguments. This still doesn't help me to pass assigned str value instead of the initialized `ctypes` int array.

Other suggestion included using SWIG typemaps but how would that work for converting a str into `int *` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Returning local arrays from functions is a tricky thing since they reside on the stack, and get destroyed when going out of scope, and thus later on when the returned address will be dereferenced, you'll most likely get a _segfault_. Either make it `static`, or dynamically allocate it, or add it as a 2nd (output) argument to your function. I'd go with #3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my comment, here are some more details about returning arrays from functions: [[SO]: Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11656532/4788546). In short, ways (each with its *pro*s and *con*s) to handle this:

1. Make the returned variable **static**
2. Dynamically allocate it (using *malloc* (family) or *new*)
3. Turn it into an additional argument for the function (and delegate management to the caller)

Getting that piece of *C* (or *C++*) code to run within the *Python* interpreter is possible in 2 ways:

- [[Python.Docs]: Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) - which creates an extension (*C* written) *Python* module

  - That's typically done using [[Python.Docs]: Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html#c-api-index). Since the boiler plate code is quite large, there are 3<sup>rd</sup>-party tools (wrappers) which make things easier (offering a simpler interface for generating the module):

    - [[SWIG]: SWIG Users Manual](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Contents.html#Contents)
    - [[ReadTheDocs.Cython]: Welcome to Cython’s Documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#welcome-to-cython-s-documentation)
    - [[ReadTheDocs.PyBind11]: Seamless operability between C++11 and Python](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable) (*C++*)
- The other way around, leaving the code in a standard *.dll* (*.so*) which can be accessed via [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

Since they both are doing the same thing, mixing them together makes no sense. So, pick the one that best fits your needs (I want to mention that running your code didn't raise the error you got).

I prepared examples for the methods. They work using *Python **3***.

##### 1. *SWIG*

- *swig_demo.h*:

  ```c
  #define OUT_BUF_SIZE 1000


  char* exposekey(const char *bIn);
  ```
- *swig_demo.c*:

  ```c
  #include <malloc.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "swig_demo.h"


  char* exposekey(const char *bIn)
  {
      char *ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20000000);
      if (ret == NULL) {
          return NULL;
      }
      printf("Message from C code...\n");
      for (int j = 0; j < OUT_BUF_SIZE; ++j) {
          ret[j] = bIn[j + 2000];
      }
      return ret;
  }
  ```
- *swig_demo.i*:

  ```c
  %module swig_demo
  %{
  #define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR
  #include "swig_demo.h"
  %}

  %newobject exposekey;
  %include "swig_demo.h"
  ```
- *test_mod.py* (shared by **all methods that create an extension module**):

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import sys 

  import data

  try:
      from _capi_demo import exposekey as capi_exposekey
  except:
      capi_exposekey = None

  try:
      from swig_demo import exposekey as swig_exposekey
  except:
      swig_exposekey = None

  try:
      from _cython_demo import exposekey as cython_exposekey
  except:
      cython_exposekey = None


  def main(*argv):
      eks = (
          capi_exposekey,
          swig_exposekey,
          cython_exposekey,
      )
      buf = data.gen_buf()
      for ek in eks:
          if ek is None:
              continue
          print("Running function: {:s} from {:s}".format(ek.__name__, ek.__module__))
          out = ek(buf)
          print("C function returned ({:d}): {:}".format(len(out), out))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```
- *data.py* (shared by **all** methods):

  ```py
  def gen_buf(pad=2000, length=1000):
      _buf = b"010011000110101110101110101010010111011101101010101"
      d, m = divmod(length, len(_buf))
      return b"\x00" * pad + _buf * d + _buf[:m]
  ```
- *Makefile.mak* (same):

  ```make
  !include <NtWin32.mak>


  .PHONY: capi swig cython ctypes

  PYTHON_DIR=c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10
  PYTHON_DIR_INC=$(PYTHON_DIR)\include
  PYTHON_DIR_LIB=$(PYTHON_DIR)\libs

  RM=del /f /q

  SRC_DIR=src
  CAPI_DEMO=capi_demo
  SWIG_DEMO=swig_demo
  CYTHON_DEMO=cython_demo
  CTYPES_DEMO=ctypes_demo
  SWIG_DEMO_WRAP=$(SWIG_DEMO)_wrap
  CYTHON_DEMO_SRC=$(CYTHON_DEMO).c

  SWIG_DEMO_SRC=$(SRC_DIR)\$(SWIG_DEMO).i
  SWIG_DEMO_WRAP_SRC=$(SWIG_DEMO_WRAP).c

  CYTHON_DEMO_PYX=$(SRC_DIR)\$(CYTHON_DEMO).pyx
  CYTHON_DEMO_SRC=$(CYTHON_DEMO).c

  CAPI_DEMO_OBJ=$(CAPI_DEMO).obj

  SWIG_DEMO_OBJ=$(SWIG_DEMO).obj
  SWIG_DEMO_WRAP_OBJ=$(SWIG_DEMO_WRAP).obj

  CAPI_OBJS=$(CAPI_DEMO_OBJ) $(SWIG_DEMO_OBJ)

  SWIG_OBJS=$(SWIG_DEMO_OBJ) $(SWIG_DEMO_WRAP_OBJ)

  CYTHON_DEMO_OBJ=$(CYTHON_DEMO).obj

  CYTHON_OBJS=$(CYTHON_DEMO_OBJ) $(SWIG_DEMO_OBJ)

  CTYPES_DEMO_OBJ=$(CTYPES_DEMO).obj

  CAPI_TARGET=_$(CAPI_DEMO).pyd
  SWIG_TARGET=_$(SWIG_DEMO).pyd
  CTYHON_TARGET=_$(CYTHON_DEMO).pyd
  CTYPES_TARGET=$(CTYPES_DEMO).dll

  #cflags=$(cflags) /UDEBUG /U_DEBUG /DNDEBUG


  all:

  clean:
      -@$(RM) *.dll *.pyd *.lib *.exp *.pdb *.obj $(SWIG_DEMO).py $(SWIG_DEMO_WRAP_SRC) $(CYTHON_DEMO_SRC)

  .c.obj:
      $(cc) $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) /I"$(SRC_DIR)" /I"$(PYTHON_DIR_INC)" /c /Fo$@ $<

  {$(SRC_DIR)}.c.obj:
      $(cc) $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvarsdll) /I"$(PYTHON_DIR_INC)" /c /Fo$@ $<

  $(SWIG_DEMO_WRAP_SRC): $(SWIG_DEMO_SRC)
      swig -python -py3 -o $@ $?

  $(CYTHON_DEMO_SRC): $(CYTHON_DEMO_PYX)
      cython.exe -3 --module-name _$(CYTHON_DEMO) -o $(CYTHON_DEMO_SRC) $?

  $(CAPI_TARGET): $(CAPI_OBJS)
      $(link) $(ldebug) $(dlllflags) /LIBPATH:"$(PYTHON_DIR_LIB)" $(conlibsdll) /OUT:$@ $?

  $(SWIG_TARGET): $(SWIG_OBJS)
      $(link) $(ldebug) $(dlllflags) /LIBPATH:"$(PYTHON_DIR_LIB)" $(conlibsdll) /OUT:$@ $?

  $(CTYHON_TARGET): $(CYTHON_OBJS)
      $(link) $(ldebug) $(dlllflags) /LIBPATH:"$(PYTHON_DIR_LIB)" $(conlibsdll) /OUT:$@ $?

  $(CTYPES_TARGET): $(CTYPES_DEMO_OBJ)
      $(link) $(ldebug) $(dlllflags) $(conlibsdll) /OUT:$@ $?


  capi: $(CAPI_TARGET)
  swig: $(SWIG_TARGET)
  cython: $(CTYHON_TARGET)
  ctypes: $(CTYPES_TARGET)
  ```

**Notes**:

- Based on comments, I changed the types in the function from *int** to *char**, because it's 4 times more compact (although it's still *~700%* inefficient since 7 bits of each char are ignored versus only one of them being used; that can be fixed, but requires *bitwise* processing)
- I also modified the index range (without changing functionality), because it makes more sense to work with low index values and add something to them in one place, instead of a high index values and subtract (the same) something in another place
- *printf* it's just dummy, to show that the *C* code gets executed
- When dealing with such arrays, it's recommended to pass their dimensions as well, to avoid out of bounds errors. Also, **error handling** is an important aspect
- I'm allocating the array and return it (the 2<sup>nd</sup> option from the beginning)
- The *.i* file is a standard *SWIG* interface file

  - Defines the module, and its exports (via *%include*)
  - One thing that is worth mentioning is the *%newobject* directive that deallocates the pointer returned by *exposekey* to avoid memory leaks
- The *.h* file just contains the function declaration, in order to be included by the *.i* file (it's not mandatory, but things are more elegant this way)
- In *Python* code (*data.py*), I generate an input buffer 3000 (padded with 2000 *NUL* bytes at the beginning) bytes long and the output is 1000 (**hardcoded values based on your example** didn't make them configurable, to keep the code simple)
- Check [[SO]: Visual Studio NMake build fails with: fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546) for details regarding *Win* builds

**Output** (on *Win*. I'll be reusing the console):

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q047276327]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> set _INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%
>
> [prompt]> set INCLUDE=%_INCLUDE%;e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\MSSDKFiles\src\Include
>
> [prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%
>
> [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts;f:\Install\pc032\SWIG\SWIGWin\4.0.1
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> tree /a /f
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is AE9E-72AC
> E:.
> |   data.py
> |   Makefile.mak
> |   test_ctypes.py
> |   test_mod.py
> |
> \---src
>         capi_demo.c
>         ctypes_demo.c
>         cython_demo.pyx
>         swig_demo.c
>         swig_demo.h
>         swig_demo.i
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> nmake /f Makefile.mak NODEBUG=1 clean swig
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.29.30148.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Could Not Find e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q047276327\*.dll
>         cl -Ox -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MD /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include" /c /Foswig_demo.obj src\swig_demo.c
> swig_demo.c
>         swig -python -py3 -o swig_demo_wrap.c src\swig_demo.i
>         cl -Ox -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MD /I"src" /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include" /c /Foswig_demo_wrap.obj swig_demo_wrap.c
> swig_demo_wrap.c
> c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include\cpython/pytime.h(120): warning C4115: 'timeval': named type definition in parentheses
> swig_demo_wrap.c(1437): warning C4100: 'args': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(1566): warning C4100: 'args': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(1578): warning C4100: 'args': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(1586): warning C4100: 'args': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(2361): warning C4100: 'clientdata': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(2537): warning C4100: 'argnum': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(2837): warning C4100: 'self': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(3157): warning C4100: 'v': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(3448): warning C4100: 'self': unreferenced formal parameter
> swig_demo_wrap.c(3467): warning C4100: 'self': unreferenced formal parameter
>         link /RELEASE  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\libs" kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:_swig_demo.pyd swig_demo.obj swig_demo_wrap.obj
>    Creating library _swig_demo.lib and object _swig_demo.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> data.py
> Makefile.mak
> src
> swig_demo.obj
> swig_demo.py
> swig_demo_wrap.c
> swig_demo_wrap.obj
> test_ctypes.py
> test_mod.py
> _swig_demo.exp
> _swig_demo.lib
> _swig_demo.pyd
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" test_mod.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Running function: exposekey from swig_demo
> Message from C code...
> C function returned (1000): b'0100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100'
>
> Done.
> ```

##### 2. *Cython*

- *cython_demo.pyx*:

  ```py
  from libc.stdlib cimport free


  cdef extern from "swig_demo.h":
      char* _exposekey "exposekey"(const char *bIn)


  def exposekey(bIn):
      cdef char *b = _exposekey(bIn)
      ret = bytes(b)
      free(b)
      return ret
  ```

**Notes**:

- I added this part as a personal exercise
- Requires *swig_demo.h* and *swig_demo.c* (the actual function)

**Output**:

> ```
> [prompt]> nmake /f Makefile.mak NODEBUG=1 clean cython
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.29.30148.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>         cython.exe -3 --module-name _cython_demo src\cython_demo.pyx
>         cl -Ox -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MD /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include" /c /Focython_demo.obj src\cython_demo.c
> cython_demo.c
> c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include\cpython/pytime.h(120): warning C4115: 'timeval': named type definition in parentheses
> src\cython_demo.c(1264): warning C4100: '__pyx_self': unreferenced formal parameter
> src\cython_demo.c(1564): warning C4100: 'def': unreferenced formal parameter
> src\cython_demo.c(2289): warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
>
> :: ------- @TODO - cfati: Truncated output (same warning) -------
>
> src\cython_demo.c(3116): warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
>         cl -Ox -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MD /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include" /c /Foswig_demo.obj src\swig_demo.c
> swig_demo.c
>         link /RELEASE  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\libs" kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:_cython_demo.pyd cython_demo.obj swig_demo.obj
>    Creating library _cython_demo.lib and object _cython_demo.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> cython_demo.c
> cython_demo.obj
> data.py
> Makefile.mak
> src
> swig_demo.obj
> test_ctypes.py
> test_mod.py
> _cython_demo.exp
> _cython_demo.lib
> _cython_demo.pyd
> __pycache__
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" test_mod.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Running function: exposekey from _cython_demo
> Message from C code...
> C function returned (1000): b'0100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100'
>
> Done.
> ```

##### 3. Plain *Python C API*

- *capi_demo.c*:

  ```c
  #define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
  #include "Python.h"
  #include "swig_demo.h"

  #define MOD_NAME "_capi_demo"


  static PyObject* PyExposekey(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
  {
      PyObject *bitsInArg = NULL, *ret = NULL;
      char *bitsOut = NULL;
      if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "S", &bitsInArg))
          return NULL;
      bitsOut = exposekey(PyBytes_AsString(bitsInArg));
      ret = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(bitsOut, OUT_BUF_SIZE);
      free(bitsOut);
      return ret;
  }


  static PyMethodDef moduleMethods[] = {
      {"exposekey", (PyCFunction)PyExposekey, METH_VARARGS, NULL},
      {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL},  // Sentinel
  };

  static struct PyModuleDef moduleDef = {
      PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, MOD_NAME, NULL, -1, moduleMethods
  };


  PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit__capi_demo(void)
  {
      return PyModule_Create(&moduleDef);
  }
  ```

**Notes**:

- Also a personal exercise
- This is what *SWIG* / *Cython* do, but "manually"
- Error handling may be improved
- Also requires the actual function

**Output**:

> ```
> [prompt]> nmake /f Makefile.mak NODEBUG=1 clean capi
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.29.30148.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>         cl -Ox -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MD /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include" /c /Focapi_demo.obj src\capi_demo.c
> capi_demo.c
> c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include\cpython/pytime.h(120): warning C4115: 'timeval': named type definition in parentheses
> src\capi_demo.c(8): warning C4100: 'self': unreferenced formal parameter
>         cl -Ox -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MD /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include" /c /Foswig_demo.obj src\swig_demo.c
> swig_demo.c
>         link /RELEASE  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\libs" kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:_capi_demo.pyd capi_demo.obj swig_demo.obj
>    Creating library _capi_demo.lib and object _capi_demo.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> capi_demo.obj
> data.py
> Makefile.mak
> src
> swig_demo.obj
> test_ctypes.py
> test_mod.py
> _capi_demo.exp
> _capi_demo.lib
> _capi_demo.pyd
> __pycache__
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" test_mod.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Running function: exposekey from _capi_demo
> Message from C code...
> C function returned (1000): b'0100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100'
>
> Done.
> ```

##### 4. *CTypes*

- *ctypes_demo.c*:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define CTYPES_DEMO_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define CTYPES_DEMO_EXPORT_API
  #endif

  #define OUT_BUF_SIZE 1000


  int CTYPES_DEMO_EXPORT_API exposekey(const char *bIn, char *bOut)
  {
      int ret = 0;
      printf("Message from C code...\n");
      for (int j = 0; j < OUT_BUF_SIZE; ++j) {
          bOut[j] = bIn[j + 2000];
          ++ret;
      }
      return ret;
  }
  ```
- *test_ctypes.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import sys

  from data import gen_buf


  OUT_BUF_SIZE = 1000
  DLL_NAME = "./ctypes_demo.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


  def main(*argv):
      dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
      exposekey = dll.exposekey
      exposekey.argtypes = (cts.c_char_p, cts.c_char_p)
      exposekey.restype = cts.c_int

      bin = cts.create_string_buffer(gen_buf())
      bout = cts.create_string_buffer(OUT_BUF_SIZE)
      print("Before ({:d}): {:} ... {:}".format(len(bout), bout.raw[:100], bout.raw[-100:]))
      ret = exposekey(bin, bout)
      print("After ({:d}): {:}".format(len(bout), bout.raw))
      print("Return code: {:d}".format(ret))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Notes**:

- This is what you started with
- It's **one** of the ways of doing things using *CTypes*
- I took *a* and turned into the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument (*bOut*). I think this is best because it's caller responsibility to allocate and deallocate the array (the 3<sup>rd</sup> option from the beginning). The alternative would be to export another function that deallocates whatever *exposekey* returns
- Return value is the number of bits set (obviously, 1000 in this case) but it's just an example
- Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions)

**Output**:

> ```
> [prompt]> nmake /f Makefile.mak NODEBUG=1 clean ctypes
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.29.30148.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>         cl -Ox -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS -D_AMD64_=1 -DWIN64 -D_WIN64  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W4 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0700 -DWINVER=0x0600  -D_MT -D_DLL -MD /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include" /c /Foctypes_demo.obj src\ctypes_demo.c
> ctypes_demo.c
>         link /RELEASE  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup -dll kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib /OUT:ctypes_demo.dll ctypes_demo.obj
>    Creating library ctypes_demo.lib and object ctypes_demo.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> ctypes_demo.dll
> ctypes_demo.exp
> ctypes_demo.lib
> ctypes_demo.obj
> data.py
> Makefile.mak
> src
> test_ctypes.py
> test_mod.py
> __pycache__
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" test_ctypes.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Before (1000): b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' ... b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> Message from C code...
> After (1000): b'0100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100101110111011010101010100110001101011101011101010100'
> Return code: 1000
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thank you soo much . this works perfectly. But like you said i'am trying to apply thins logic to complex functions/projects , hence the use of SWIG.

Comment: In the above code you are defining the input array to be passed, if have an input string of 0's and 1's (type= python str) how do i pass that as input to this ctypes func?  Thanks  again.

Comment: If you want to pass a string, you need to change the function (so its `bits` argument is a `char*`), and also from _Python_, its `argtypes`. It's definitely better to store a **0/1** value (1bit) in a `char` (8bits) than in an `int` (32bits), however it's still 700% inefficient from the storage's *PoV* (as the `char` 7 other bits aren't used). While on this subject, if changing `bits` wouldn't it be a good idea to also change `out` (to `char*`)? Or you could go the easy way (initialize `bits` like this): `for i, char in enumerate(your_string):` `bits[2000 + i] = ord(char) - ord("0")`.

Comment: Did you give the _swig_ variant a try?

Comment: tried what you suggested passing to char * and did the bit conversion at the c end using atoi(), instead of ord() at python end. Thank you