# How can I pass an array as a return value through a thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I am working on a function that creates a thread and calculates the Fibonacci sequence to a certain user inputted value. For example, if a user enters `5`, the output will be: `0 1 1 2 3 5`

However, the sequence must be calculated in the created thread, and the results have to be printed out after the thread is exited.

I can create the thread and calculate the sequence, but I need to pass the array `fibSequence[]` back to the original thread using `pthread_exit` and `pthread_join`. I am having trouble figuring out the syntax and can't find any examples of people passing arrays through.

What I have so far:
I created a function `fib_runner()` that is called by a newly created thread. The Fibonacci sequence is created and placed into the array `fibSequence[]`. I need to pass this back through to the main function. I am temporarily printing out the sequence in the function, but it should be printed in the main.

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* fib_runner(void* arg)
{
    int *limit_ptr = (int*) arg;
    int limit = *limit_ptr;
    int fibSequence[limit];

    int size = sizeof(fibSequence)/sizeof(fibSequence[0]);
    printf("Size: %d\n", size);

    fibSequence[0] = 0;
    fibSequence[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= size; i++)
    {
        fibSequence[i] = fibSequence[i-1] + fibSequence[i-2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", fibSequence[i]);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int limit;
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, fib_runner, &limit);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the array is a local variable, so it would go out of scope when the function exits.  You need to dynamically allocate memory for it instead:

```
int *fibSequence = malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);
```

Then return this pointer from the function:

```
return fibSequence;
```

In your `main` function, you then pass the address of a pointer to receive this value.  Then you can print the content of the array.  When you're done, be sure to `free` it:

```
int *fibSequence;
pthread_join(tid, (void **)&fibSequence);

for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", fibSequence[i]);
}
free(fibSequence);
```

Also, you don't need `size` in your thread function, since it is the same as `limit`, and the way you currently calculate it won't work anyway since you now have a pointer instead of an array.  Your loop limit in `fib_runner` also goes one past the end of the array.  The exit condition should be `i < size`, not `i <= size`.

Comment: When I use return, doesn't that make pthread_exit unreachable?
Also, when I initialize *fibSequence with malloc, should I do that before or after I initialize its size with limit?

Comment: @NamitPatel Returning from a thread function is the same as calling `pthread_exit`.  They are interchangeable.  For `fibSequence`, the line above that calls `malloc` is all you need (plus error checking to ensure `malloc` was successful).

Comment: Ok, I removed pthread_exit, I didn't know return was the same. Also, when I call malloc, I don't think it is initializing the correct number of elements. For example, when I enter 5 as the input, it prints 
0 1 0 0 0

Comment: Never mind it was an error on my end. Used size instead of limit in my for loop so it was ending early. Thanks for the help! Program works!

Answer (score 0):

All the threads running within a process share the same address space, file descriptors, stack and other process related attributes.

Threads are sharing memory by definition, they do not own anything except stack and local variables;

If you make `fibSequence[limit]` global then all threads will have access to it.

You can also declare `fibSequence[limit]` on the stack in `main` and pass pointer to it to your thread.

To pass multiple arguments it is convenient to wrap them up in a structure. 
The solutions below employ:

```
struct arg_struct {
    int limit;
    int *ptrFib;
}args;
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct arg_struct {
    int limit;
    int *ptrFib;
}args;

void* fib_runner(void* arg)
{
    struct arg_struct *a = (struct arg_struct *) arg;
    int size = a->limit;
    int * fibSequence = a->ptrFib;  

    fibSequence[0] = 0;
    fibSequence[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= size; i++){
        fibSequence[i] = fibSequence[i-1] + fibSequence[i-2];
    }    
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int limit;
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    int fibSequence[limit];

    struct arg_struct argF;
    argF.limit = limit;
    argF.ptrFib = fibSequence;

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, fib_runner, &argF);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++){
        printf("%d ", fibSequence[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Number: 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
0 1 1 2 3 5
```

The solution with global variable `argF` is of course possible but it is less elegant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct arg_struct {
    int limit;
    int *ptrFib;
}args;

struct arg_struct argF;

void* fib_runner()
{
    int size = argF.limit;
    int * fibSequence = argF.ptrFib;

    fibSequence[0] = 0;
    fibSequence[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= size; i++){
        fibSequence[i] = fibSequence[i-1] + fibSequence[i-2];
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int limit;
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    int fibSequence[limit];

    argF.limit = limit;
    argF.ptrFib = fibSequence;

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, fib_runner, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++){
        printf("%d ", fibSequence[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable length arrays are not allowed at file scope, and returning a pointer to an array declared locally invokes undefined behavior since it goes out of scope.

Comment: The trouble I'm having with this solution is that I don't get the value for limit until the main function. So I don't know how I could initialize it as a global variable when I don't have limit until the user enters it. Unless there's a way to do it that I'm not thinking about.
EDIT: What dbush said.

Comment: @dbush Thank you for your comment! I did not made myself clear. What I meant was to declare `fibSequence[limit]` in the `main`. The life span of such array is equal to the life of the program.

Comment: @NamitPatel This sequence will work in C99: `scanf("%d", &limit); int fibSequence[limit];` or use `dbush` dynamic approach.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass in a value of `void *` to `pthread_exit` which is `pthread_exit(( void * ) &fibSequence`, once that function is called the passed in value will populate the second argument to `pthread_join`, the second argument will be a pointer to a pointer `void **` it will hold the values passed in to `pthred_exit`