# I am trying to print out the phone number but i am getting an error

Tags: c, arrays

just to let you all know im pretty new at programming and i think I am just missing something small but I dont know what it is. When I compile my code I am getting this error "format `%d` expects a matching `int` argument [`-Wformat=`]". I have tried many things. I have tried making all the function types to `char` and them all to `int`. I get similar errors.

```
char *phoneInput(void)
{
    char phone[11];

    printf("Input the politicians phone number with no spaces: ");
    fgets(phone, 10, stdin);
    return 0;
}

char  printPhone(char phone[11])
{
    printf("- Phone Number: (%d%d%d)%d%d%d-%d%d%d%d", phone[0], phone[1], phone[2], 
              phone[3], phone[5], phone[6], phone[7], phone[8], phone[9]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. That `phoneInput` functions looks very suspect...

Comment: And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear if you read the words. `**char** phone[11]` and *format '%d' expects a matching **'int`** argument* should be pretty self explanatory.

Comment: `phone` is local to `phoneInput` function. It will not be visible outside of that function scope. You have to declare `phone` as a pointer and dynamically allocate memory for it and return `phone` pointer from `phoneInput` function. In function `printPhone`, function specification should be `%c` instead of `%d`.

Comment: I tried using %c instead of %d and i get a similar error format ‘"%c’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]"

Comment: Basically your error is because you have 10 `%d`s and only nine matching arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one more argument for your `printf` statement. Add `phone[4]` to your `printf` like this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char *phoneInput(void)
{
    char phone[11];

    printf("Input the politicians phone number with no spaces: ");
    fgets(phone, 10, stdin);
    return 0;
}

char  printPhone(char phone[11])
{
    printf("- Phone Number: (%d%d%d)%d%d%d-%d%d%d%d", phone[0], phone[1], phone[2],
              phone[3], phone[4], phone[5], phone[6], phone[7], phone[8], phone[9]);

    return 0;
}
```

But I don't understand is, why all your functions have a return type of `char*` or `char` when in fact from both functions, you are returning a `0` only.

Comment: Can you return a character array?

Comment: @xing, ah yeah! good catch! I edited accordingly.

Comment: @sarah, short answer is no. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c). There could be ways send to values out from a function but straight up returning the address of a local char array will not work.

Comment: @xing Got it thanks!