# Segmentation Error in C code when i try to read the hex file

Tags: c

1. Im trying to read a hex file, i have partitioned my code into two parts, load file data to buffer and second part access the buffer to read specific region data. The compilation is clean but when i run test, it throws segmentation fault

   #include 
       #include 
       #include

   ```
   char *fip_buffer;
   char *emmc_pattern_buffer;

   char hex_pattern() { 
       FILE *fileptr;
       char *buffer;
           long filelen;
       int i,j;


       fileptr = fopen("fip.hex", "rb");         
       if( fileptr == NULL ) {
          printf("cannot open file");// exit(1);
        }
       fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);          
       filelen = ftell(fileptr);            
       rewind(fileptr);                      
       fip_buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char)); 

       for(i = 0; i < filelen; i++) {
          fread(fip_buffer+i, 1, 1, fileptr); 

       }


       fclose(fileptr); // Close the file
       return(fip_buffer);
   }



   char hex_pattern_read(int a, int filelen){
   char mem[8],mem2[7];
   int i,j;
   for(i=a;i<filelen;i++){
         mem[j]=fip_buffer[i];
         mem[8]='\0';
         j++;
         if(j==8){strcpy(mem2,mem);j=0; break;
          }
      } 
      emmc_pattern_buffer=mem2;
      return(emmc_pattern_buffer);
   }




   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   printf("Reading hex file");
   int i,j;
   hex_pattern();
   int len = strlen(fip_buffer);
   printf("size of buffer is=%d\n%s\n",len,fip_buffer);
   for(i=0; i<2; i++){
     // printf("Entered loop1");
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
      int temp = (j*8)+(128*i);
       hex_pattern_read(temp,len);
      printf("%s\n",emmc_pattern_buffer);
     }
   }
   return 0;

   }
   ```

Comment: How is C++ relevant to the question?

Comment: Your code has multiple issues. Some of them should generate warnings from the compiler. Have you reviewed the compiler output?

Comment: `printf("%s\n",pattern)`. That causes undefined behaviour because `%s` requires a character buffer (ie, `char *`) but you give it a single `char`.

Comment: `return(mem2)`. That also causes undefined behaviour as `mem2` is a local array variable and must not be returned to the caller.

Comment: `return(mem2); fclose(fileptr);`. That results in a resource leak as the `fclose` statement never runs since it is after the `return`.

Comment: `char mem[8],mem2[7]; mem[8]='\0'; strcpy(mem2,mem)` That causes a buffer overrun as array indices start from 0 and hence `mem[8]` is an invalid access. Also, `strcpy` includes the terminating NUL in the copy and hence having `mem2` smaller than `mem` will result in overrunning `mem2`.

Comment: I highly recommend a change of learning materials. Whatever you are using is doing you few favours. If this is intended to be C++, [here is a list of generally recognized as good texts and references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you kaylum, with the above suggestions my code did work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to say, since `mem2` is declared by:

```
char mem[8],mem2[7];
```

is, that you attempt to return a pointer to `char` with:

```
return(mem2);
```

as opposed to what it is declared in the definition of `hex_pattern()` as return type; a value of type `int`:

`int hex_pattern(int a) {}`

While this on its own may cause the `NULL` pointer for itself (presume the compiler would let it pass with a warning at least), You even get `NULL` if you would declare/define `hex_pattern()` the right way with:

`char* hex_pattern (int a){}`

---

`mem2` is a *pointer* to the first element of the **local** `char` array of `mem2[]`, but the array of `mem2[]`is not existing anymore after you will leave `hex_pattern()` back to the caller, here `main()`.

The array of `mem2[]`is of storage class `auto` by default (when you omitting a specific storage class) and an object of that storage class is only alive in the function it was defined/declared. It is determined when leaving the function scope.

So, the pointer points back to `NULL`, because at the address the pointer is pointing to, is no longer a valid object with a valid value stored.

If you really want to return the whole array of `mem2[]`, which isn´t possible on its own, you can find good alternatives best explained here: [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c)

---

Also you should never incorporate statements after `return`, like you did it with:

```
 return(mem2);
 fclose(fileptr); // Close the file
```

Simply because of the reason that these statements do not get executed. `return` is the final statement. Everything what comes thereafter is ignored.