# How to return arrays from functions?

Tags: c

In C programming How to return arrays from a user-defined-function?I have tried doing it but always returns an error.Are there any Exceptions to this? or you just can't return functions in c Programming?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c)

Comment: Can you show us the code btw? not that it's 100% necessary, but it would help.

Comment: Arrays cannot be returned.  The usual substitute is to return a pointer to an array of data.

Comment: Learner: Rather than only describe how code performed, "I have tried doing it but always returns an error.", better to post code.