# Trying to return an Array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I've been trying to return an array in C. I'm mostly acquainted with Java (where it's comparatively easier to return an array).

This is what I'm trying to do right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * duplicates(int[],int);

int main() {
    int arr[] = {3,5,6,5,9,5,10,11,3};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int * tempArray = duplicates(arr,n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d \t",tempArray[i]);
    }

}

int * duplicates(int arr[], int n) {
    int tempArray[n];
    int r = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                for(int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
                    if(arr[i] == tempArray[k]) {
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 0) {
                    tempArray[r++] = arr[i];
                    flag = 0;
                } else {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return tempArray;

}
```

And this, to no surprise - crashes my program. How I can return an array in C, because that feels like a bare-minimum, something I should know before I can move further into the language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c)

Comment: Just nitpicking (I enjoy that): In java you can't return an array, only references to arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just allocate the memory like here [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c)

```
int * duplicates(int arr[], int n) {
    int *tempArray;
    ...
    tempArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    if (tempArray == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    ...
```

This will work. Google why you should 'dynamically allocate the memory' and 'pointer'.

Comment: [Do not cast the result of `malloc()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Also, it is preferable to avoid `sizeof(type)`. So `malloc(n * sizeof *tempArray)` would be preferable here. It makes it clearer what the memory is used for, and since `sizeof` is not a function, the braces can be omitted by putting `n` in front.

Answer (score 0):

the array you created inside function `duplicate` has automatic storage duration since it's on the stack of function unlike in java in which arrays are objects and allocated on the heap. anyway I just wanted to add some NOTE which is don't use `VLA`(variable length arrays) like `int array[n]` instead use literals like `int array[50]` since VLA generate a lot of assembly code(affect performance a tiny bit) and can have security problems like stack overflows or cause the program to crash. Also, not all compilers implement it(portability issues).