# Assigning a value to an array of char in C

Tags: arrays, c

I am making a program in C which generates all the combinations of the given input.
For example,if input is `ABCD`,then it will give me an array of strings which will be
`{"A","B","C","D","AB","BC","CD","ABC","BCD","ABCD"}` without scrambling the word.
Here is my code:

```
char **word_generator(char *word)
{
    char *combinations[500];
    int index = 0;
    int val = 0;
    int index1  = 0;
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0;i < pow(len,2);i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < len - index;j++)
        {
            val = 0;
            for (int k = j;k < j+index+1;k++)
            {
                combinations[index1][val] = word[k];
                printf("%c ",word[k]);
                val += 1;
            }
            printf("\n");
            if (val == len)
            {
                return combinations;
            }
            index1 += 1;
        }
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

I have tested the code and if gives perfect results if I don't bother about array and return value and just print the output.
But there are two problems in it.

1. It gives the error `function returning address of a local variable`.
2. Some problem is in the line `combinaitons[index1][val] = word[k];` because I have tested the code and everything goes fine before that line.

Comment: Have you learned about the difference between the stack and the heap?  A variable allocated with malloc() goes on the heap, and persists after the function returns.   A variable declared like char foo[10]; goes on the stack and disappears.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `combinations` is an array of pointers, but you've never allocated memory for them to point to. Also, you can't return a local array, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c

Comment: _Side note:_ `int len = strlen(word); for (int i = 0; i < pow(len,2); i++)` is _very_ slow. The `pow` function is slow [and can be replaced with `len * len`]. And, it is called on each loop iteration instead of just once. You can replace with: `int len = strlen(word); int len2 = len * len; for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++)`

Comment: Hmm, I'd also expect `""` in the output set.  Aditya76, what output set should result from `word_generator("")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
            combinations[index1][val] = word[k];
```

But all elements of `combinations` are clearly uninitalized. Anything can happen.

Comment: Then how can I initialize all elements of this array because I don't know the size of it because user can give any word so it's size may vary

Comment: @Aditya76: Have you reached `malloc` yet? But I don't understand your code so I can't adapt it even if you have.

Comment: I don't know why you can't understand my code. it's pretty easy to understand if you try to.

Comment: @Aditya76: To start off with, essentially no algorithm increments index at two levels of nested loops.