# Matrix addition in C getting 0 in the first addition only

Tags: c, matrix

In the output, I get every addition right except the first one. In the output, it shows this :

```
enter the number of rows and columns of matrices to be added : 2 2
For matrix [a], Enter The Element at (0,0): 2
For matrix [a], Enter The Element at (0,1): 2
For matrix [a], Enter The Element at (1,0): 2
For matrix [a], Enter The Element at (1,1): 2

the matrix [a] is : 
2 2 
2 2 

For matrix [b], Enter The Element at (0,0): 22
For matrix [b], Enter The Element at (0,1): 2
For matrix [b], Enter The Element at (1,0): 
2
For matrix [b], Enter The Element at (1,1): 2

the matrix [b] is : 
22 2 
2 2 

Resultant matrix [c] : 
0 4 
4 4
```

I don't know what caused the "0" in the position (0,0) of resultant matrix. I tried changing the i++ to ++i just to make sure its not the prefix and postfix problem but it doesn't seem to be it. I cannot figure out why I get 0 only in (0, 0). Please do help as I'm new to C. This is my code :

```
int add(int a[][20], int b[][20], int c[][20], int row, int col);
int row, col;
int a[100][20]; 
int b[100][20]; 
int c[100][20];
int main()
{
    printf("enter the number of rows and columns of matrices to be added : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("For matrix [a], Enter The Element at (%d,%d): ",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nthe matrix [a] is : \n");
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("%d", a[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("For matrix [b], Enter The Element at (%d,%d): ",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nthe matrix [b] is : \n");
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("%d", b[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    c[i][j] = add(a, b, c, row, col);
    printf("Resultant matrix [c] : \n");
    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            printf("%d", c[i][j]);
            printf (" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int add(int a[][20], int b[][20], int c[][20], int row, int col){
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];}}
    return c[i][j];
}
```

Comment: `c[i][j] = add(a, b, c, row, col);` -> `add(a, b, c, row, col);`. And make `add` a void function, returning `c[i][j]` makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you, tried that and code worked ^^ can I ask why returning an array made no sense? also, if I HAD to do this question with "int" instead of "void" would it be possible to not get an error?

Comment: Returning an array would make sense, if it was possible in C, but it's  not. And `return c[i][j]` does not return an array, but it returns a single element of the array. BTW 'i' and 'j' are out of range anyway after the end of the loops

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c

Answer (score 1):

As the mentioned comments you don't need to retrun anything for matrix sumation because you have already changed that matrix by reference. Remove `int` retrun value of `add` and try something like that:

```
#include "stdio.h"
void add(int a[][20], int b[][20], int c[][20], int row, int col);
int row, col;
int a[100][20];
int b[100][20];
int c[100][20];
int main()
{
    printf("enter the number of rows and columns of matrices to be added : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("For matrix [a], Enter The Element at (%d,%d): ",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nthe matrix [a] is : \n");
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("%d", a[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("For matrix [b], Enter The Element at (%d,%d): ",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nthe matrix [b] is : \n");
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("%d", b[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    add(a, b, c, row, col);
    printf("Resultant matrix [c] : \n");
    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            printf("%d", c[i][j]);
            printf (" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void add(int a[][20], int b[][20], int c[][20], int row, int col){
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];}}
}
```