# Converting a Char Array into an Int array using a Function

Tags: arrays, c, atoi

I have been tasked with converting a char* array into an int array using a function. I'm new to C so I do apologize if this is a simple fix or an easy solution that I have just failed to notice.

This is the code I currently have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int convert(char* str[], int length);

int main(void)
{
    int result[50], i, length = 4;
    char *str[] = {"7", "1", "14", "15"};

    result[4] = convert(str, 4);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {     
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int convert(char* str[], int length)
{
    int i;
    int arr[50];

    for(i = 0; i > length; i++)
    arr[i] = atoi(str[i]);

    return arr[50];
}
```

The output is currently this:

```
832 832 832 832
```

Essentially, what the code is attempting to do is convert

```
char *str[] = {"7", "1", "14", "15"};
```

into this (output):

```
7 1 14 15
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: `return arr[50]` that returns a single `int`. So it straight away says you can't possibly get results for multiple ints. Also `arr[50]` is past the end of the array. Perhaps you are trying to return the whole array as a result. See the duplicate post for the correct way to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c)

Comment: `for(i = 0; i > length; i++)` is obviously wrong. As is the senseless `return arr[50];`. You have to study arrays before using arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the definition of `convert()` above above `main()` so the prototype is not required.  As you know the size of the `result` array it is cleaner to pass it in as an argument, and as @kaylum noted above, the return type of `int` is clearly incorrect.  The loop is wrong (should be `i < length`).  You cannot return a local array `arr` even if you tried as it will be out of scope when function returns.  `return arr[50]` refers to an element that is out of bounds.  In `main()`, the expression `result[4] =` sets the 4th element and rest of result contains undefined data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_LEN(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A))

void convert(int length, char *str[length], int result[length]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result[i] = atoi(str[i]);
}

int main(void) {
    char *str[] = {"7", "1", "14", "15"};
    int result[ARRAY_LEN(str)];
    convert(ARRAY_LEN(str), str, result);
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN(result); i++) {
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Consider using `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` so you can implement error handling (`atoi()` returns 0 on error).