# C++ return value type does not match the function type (char array)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just trying to return a char array from my function. I read quite a few posts and people were just suggesting to return char*. The compiler does let me use char* as a return type, but I want to return an array, not a pointer to it. This is what my function looks like:

```
char IsValid(char num[]) {
   char newNum[101];
   // do stuff
   return newNum;
}
```

It seems that the return type does match the function type. They are both char. What's going on?

Comment: `char[101]` and `char` are not the same type.

Comment: Any function beginning with any form of “`is`” should return a _boolean_ and nothing else, Nor should it _modify_ its arguments in any way. This is definitely an XY Problem. What exactly are you  trying to accomplish?

Comment: The function returns `char`. `newNum` is an array of 101 `char`s. They are not both `char`.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11656532/16217248) if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of a function cannot be an array. Since we are here, the `num` parameter of your function is not an array, it's a pointer.

Anyway in C++ you shouldn't use C arrays. Use `std::array` or `std::vector`. Those can be parameter types and return types.

Answer (score -1):

```
char IsValid(char num[]) {
   char newNum[101];
   // do stuff
   return newNum;
}
```

Arrays sometimes "decay" into [pointers](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) (meaning they turn into pointers and have to be treated as such). So to make this function capable of returning it, you'd need to set the return value as a char pointer (`char*`), so that'd look like this:

```
char* IsValid(char num[])
```

*Also, you can't have a parameter of type char[], because arrays are just pointers with constant sizes, so you'd need to further change the function to:* **(THIS IS FALSE INFORMATION, YOU CAN HAVE PARAMETERS OF TYPE `type[]` AND I AM SORRY FOR THE MISTAKE).**

Then you can do something like this:

```
char* IsValid(char num[]) {
    static char newArr[100];
    // that static keyword, in this case
    // makes our new array act as if it was a global variable
    // do stuff 
    return newArr;
}

int main() {
    char arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    char* return_arr = IsValid(arr);
}
```

[More info about the static keyword](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/static-local-variables/)

That being said, what bolov has said is correct. For arrays like this, it's better to use the standard library's container [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for dealing with arrays of static (unchanging) sizes, or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for arrays with dynamic sizing.

I wish you luck on your C++ journey!

Comment: "Arrays in C++ don't really exist, they're just pointers" this is false. Arrays do exist, they are their own data type and differ from pointers. It's just that in some contexts arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: Perhaps we should just wait to see of OP offers any new information before trying to solve an indeterminate problem...

Comment: @bolov I will admit it was a gross oversimplification of the whole topic, I was just rushing it along a bit and generalising for the sake of brevity. You are right, they are different. Even in the assembly level, pointers would be direct addresses while arrays would equate to reserved bytes in "section .bss" and the section is used for local common variable storage. So yeah, sorry about that, kinda glossed over it while trying to write everything.

Comment: @Dúthomhas It is true that it is indeterminate, however I just wanted to answer exactly what they asked and then give them additional info on why or why not. This certainly isn't how you'd do proper C++ but it's a start and helping OP achieve what they want and then providing info on its correctness felt appropriate (I did make a mistake which bolov corrected).