# Is it correct to return a hard-coded array needed for recursion in C?

Tags: c, return, hardcode, multiple-return-values

I realized that I need my C function to return 2 values and not just one, so is it correct to return a hard-coded array in this way?

```
int * funct(){
    if(condition1){
       return{1,1}
    }else{
       return{1,-1}
    }
}
```

I need this return array structure for implementing my minimax algorithm. Here's some code for context, but it's not necessary (the example above should be enough to deliver the idea).

```
//Requires: board, depth & true if we're playing max player/ false if min player 
//Effects: returns best score & col
int * minimax(int ** board, int depth, bool maxPlayer){
  int newscore;
  int * validLocations= getValidLocations(board);
  bool gameOver= gameOver(board);
  if (depth==0 || gameOver){
    if (gameOver){
      if(isWin(board, COMPUTER)){
      return {-1, +10000};
      }
    else if(isWin(board,PLAYER)){
      return {-1, -10000};
      }
    else{
      return {-1, 0};; //tie
      }
    }
    else{ //depth is 0
      return {-1, boardScore(AI)};
    }
  }
  if(maxPlayer){
    int val= INT_MIN;
    int bestCol= validLocations[0];
    int validLocationsIndex=0;
    int col= validLocations[0];
    while (col!=-1  && validLocationsIndex<7){
      int ** possibleBoard= copyBoard(board);
      insert(possibleBoard, col, COMPUTER);
      newscore= minimax(possibleBoard, depth-1, false)[1];
      freeBoard(possibleBoard);
      if (newscore>val){
        val= newscore;
        bestCol= col;
      }
      validLocationsIndex++;
      col= validLocations[validLocationsIndex];
      return {bestCol, newscore};
      
    }
  }
  else{
    int val= INT_MAX;
    int validLocationsIndex=0;
    int col= validLocations[0];
    while (col!=-1  && validLocationsIndex<7){
      int ** possibleBoard= copyBoard(board);
      insert(possibleBoard, col, PLAYER);
      newscore= minimax(possibleBoard, depth-1, true)[1];
      freeBoard(possibleBoard);
      if (newscore<val){
        val= newscore;
        bestCol= col;
      }
      validLocationsIndex++;
      col= validLocations[validLocationsIndex];
      return {bestCol, newscore};
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Rather than an arbitrary array that's handled with implicit knowledge from the developer, I would say it'd be better to create a `struct` of the data you are returning. The calling code can then reference the parts it wants explicitly, by name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c) It's not at all clear to me why we should care that the calling function is recursive.

Comment: Does it work like that though, in terms of syntax? Because in a recursive function it is easier to have the values hardcoded & I wanna add to that value in each recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. automatic storage duration arrays cannot be returned in C language.
2. `return {-1, boardScore(AI)};` this syntax is wrong
3. You can use `struct`s as structs are passed bt value
4. You can use compound literals

```
typedef struct
{
    int data[2];
}mystruct;

mystruct funct(int condition)
{
    if(condition)
    {
       return (mystruct){{1,-1}};
    }else
    {
       (mystruct){{1, -1}};
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, point 1 is simply untrue (at least a pointer to the object can be returned): Nothing prevents anybody from doing that. It is not even forbidden. Even more unfortunately, nothing prevents anybody from *accessing* memory of objects whose lifetime has expired, even though that *is* forbidden. The language has no means of tracking object lifetime beyond static analysis. C is simply a very unsafe language.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica no it is true. returning pointer to automatic storage variable which has gone out of the scope is UB

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure but would think that as long as the memory is not accessed, the behavior is defined (e.g. one could print the pointer value with %p). Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica what is the point of returning a reference to an invalid object? Pseudo examples like printing the reference only mess up beginners. They will read your comment and start to think that is OK to return it. They will not remember that you wrote about some border cases.

Comment: What is the point is not the question ;-).