# Function does not return byte array as expected in Visual Studio

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio

I'm having an issue retuning a byte array in Visual Studio. The following code outputs as expected in online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/

The expected output is an array of 8 bytes: `BB-CC-C3-02-5C-11-6D-00`

And the online compiler outputs the same as expected:

```
*******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t * createByteArray(float power, int power_coefficient);

int main()
{

    float power = 4444;
    int power_coefficient = 1;
    
    
    uint8_t * returned_ptr = createByteArray(power, power_coefficient);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < returned_ptr[3]+6; i++)
        printf("%02X-", returned_ptr[i]);

    return 0;
}

uint8_t * createByteArray(float power, int power_coefficient)
{

    uint16_t power_ushort = (uint16_t)(power * power_coefficient);
    uint8_t bytes_power[2];
    bytes_power[0] = (uint8_t)((power_ushort >> 8) & 0xFF);
    bytes_power[1] = (uint8_t)(power_ushort & 0xFF);
    uint8_t firstHalf_power = bytes_power[0];
    uint8_t secondHalf_power = bytes_power[1];


    int parity = (int)firstHalf_power + (int)secondHalf_power;
    uint16_t parity_ushort = (uint16_t)(parity);
    uint8_t bytes_parity[2];
    bytes_parity[0] = (uint8_t)((parity_ushort >> 8) & 0xFF);
    bytes_parity[1] = (uint8_t)(parity_ushort & 0xFF);
    uint8_t firstHalf_parity = bytes_parity[0];
    uint8_t secondHalf_parity = bytes_parity[1];

    uint8_t telegram_set_power[8] = {0xBB, 0xCC, 0xC3, 0x02, secondHalf_power, firstHalf_power, secondHalf_parity, firstHalf_parity};
    
    uint8_t * ptr = telegram_set_power;
    
    return ptr;

}
```

But in Visual Studio 2022, the same code returns the following output:

```
AA-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-CC-A8-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-A8-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-45-64-DD-8D-FA-7F-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-64-00-1B-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-36-9D-EA-8D-FA-7F-00-00-A0-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-CC-F6-11-AE-2C-00-00-00-10-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-D0-F5-11-AE-2C-00-00-00-1C-00-1B-00-00-01-00-00-E0-F5-11-AE-2C-00-00-00-14-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-
```

I have been trying to fix it but failed. What could be the reason for this?

**Edit:** This happens when I compile as 64 bit. When I compile under x86 it works. But I need to compile as x64 for some other reasons.

Comment: Tip: If you define your function before `main()` there's no need to declare it in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your display function is correct? That looks really strange, especially without explanation. First step is to narrow down, preferably with a debugger, if it's a display problem, or a data problem.

Comment: I now noticed something. This happens when I compile as 64 bit. When I compile under x86 it works, But I need to sue x64 for some other reasons.

Comment: If you're having architecture issues, then you probably have a big bug in your code. You still need to narrow this down to display or data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `createByteArray` is returning a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), i.e. a pointer to an object that no longer exists when the function returns.

The array `telegram_set_power` is a local array. Therfore, its [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) ends when the function `createByteArray` returns. The function `createByteArray` is returning a pointer to this no longer existant array.

Dereferencing the dangling pointer `returned_ptr` in the function `main` will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This explains why your program appears to work on one platform, but doesn't work on another platform.

In order to solve this problem, you have the following options:

1. Declare the array inside the function `main` instead of inside the function `createByteArray` and pass a pointer to this array to the function `createByteArray`. In that case, it would probably be appropriate to rename the function `createByteArray` to `initByteArray`, since it no longer creates the array, but rather only initializes it.
2. In the function `createByteArray`, instead of making `telegram_set_power` a local array whose lifetime ends when the function returns, you could allocate memory for the array using the function [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). That way, you have full control of the lifetime of the array. Its lifetime will only end when you call [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free). Therefore, it is safe to return a pointer to such an object.

Generally, solution #1 is the easier solution, because if you use solution #2, you will have to remember to call `free` when you no longer need the memory. Otherwise, you will have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

See the following question for more information on how to return an array in C:

[Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11656532/12149471)

Comment: What could be the remedy? I also tried to pass a pointer as a function parameter I still get weird results.

Comment: @pnatk: I have now expanded my answer to offer two solutions.

Comment: I tried first  one worked thanks