# Array is returning blank - CS50 N0 V0w3ls

Tags: c, function, char, cs50, c-strings

I am stuck on the [n0 v0w3ls exercise from CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/2/no-vowels/). I can´t figure out how to have an non-blank output. I am getting completely lost in the data types transformation between string/char and assigning new values to the output char. I have tried so many combinations, I don´t understand the differences anymore. Right now, my program works in the debugger but the output is blank. Any help greatly appreciated ;)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char replace(string input);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c \n", replace(argv[1]));
    }

}

char replace(string input)
{
    int n = strlen(input);
    //n+1 as I read the last char should be a '\0' to be recognised as a string
    char s[n+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //printf("%c\n", input[i]);
        switch (input[i])
        {
            case 97:
                s[i] = '6' ;
                break;
            case 101:
                s[i] = '3';
                break;
            case 105:
                s[i] = '1';
                break;
            case 111:
                s[i] = '0';
                break;
            default:
                s[i] = input[i];
                break;
        }
    }
    return s[n];
}
```

The aim is to replace vowels by numbers. I have tried

- taking the input as a string
- looping on each character of that string
- if the character is a vowel > replaces it in my output string else keep as is
- return my output char array/string ?

```
// Write a function to replace vowels with numbers
// Get practice with strings
// Get practice with command line
// Get practice with switch

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string replace(string input);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s \n", replace(argv[1]));
    }

}

string replace(string input)
{
    int n = strlen(input);
    string s[n+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //printf("%c\n", input[i]);
        switch (input[i])
        {
            case 'a':
                s[i] = "6" ;
                break;
            case 'e':
                s[i] = "3";
                break;
            case 'i':
                s[i] = "1";
                break;
            case 'o':
                s[i] = "0";
                break;
            default:
                s[i] = &input[i];
                break;
        }
    }
    s[n+1] = "\0";
    return s[n];
}
```

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII codes, use character literals: `'A'` intead of `97`.

Comment: You never added a null terminator to `s`. `s[n]` is where it should be, but you never initialized it. And what's the point of returning that, anyway?

Comment: You're missing a case for `U`.

Comment: The function needs to return a string, not `char`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c

Comment: What would you return to the main function? I tried switching to a string and replace '' by "" but now the output is a bunch of ???

Comment: Did you follow the above link?

Comment: `string` is not a data type in C. Do you have the definition of `string`? And you don't need to manipulate the whole `s` array when you only return a single element from it. Are you sure you want to return only a single element of `s`?

Comment: `s[n+1] = "\0";` causes UB.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The CS50 course uses `string` as a alias for `char*`.

Comment: @Barmar: The [text of the assignment](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/2/no-vowels/) states that the letter `u` should not be replaced. Don't ask me why. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [text of the assignment](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/2/no-vowels/) states the following:

> Your program must contain a function called replace which takes a string input and returns a string output.

It also states:

> The input parameter for the replace function will be argv[1] and the return value is the converted word.

However, you declared the function `replace` like this:

```
char replace(string input);
```

This is wrong. According to the instructions, the function should return a `string` instead of a single `char`, like this:

```
string replace(string input);
```

Another issue is that the line

```
return s[n];
```

is wrong, because `s[n]` is a character, but you need to return a `string` (i.e. several characters).

You could write

```
return s;
```

instead, which will return a reference to the string `s`. However, this will also not work, for the following reason:

In contrast to data types such as `int`, `char`, `float` and `double`, the CS50 data type `string` is special. A variable of type `string` does not actually represent several characters. It rather represents a reference to a character array. It is not a character array itself. The technical term for such a reference is a "pointer". You will learn all about pointers and their relationship to the data type `string` in [week 4 of CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/weeks/4/).

When you write

```
return s;
```

you are not returning the values of the characters in the array `s`, but rather a reference to the array `s`.

However, once the function `replace` returns, the local array `s` will cease to exist. Therefore, it does not make sense to return a reference to that non-existant array.

There are several possible solutions to this problem, such as

1. use a global array instead of a local array, so that the lifetime of the array does not end when the function returns, or
2. create a new array using dynamically allocated memory, so that you have full control of the lifetime of the array, or
3. instead of writing to a separate array, simply overwrite the input array `argv[1]` and return a reference to that array.

I do not recommend that you use solution #1, because that solution is rather ugly.

Solution #2 would generally be a good solution, but this would require knowledge that you will only acquire in week 4 of CS50. Since you probably still are in week 2, I do not recommend that you attempt this until after you completed week 4 of the course.

Therefore, I recommend that you use solution #3 for now. Here is an example:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string replace(string input);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", replace(argv[1]));
    }
}

string replace(string input)
{
    int n = strlen(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        switch (input[i])
        {
            case 'a':
                input[i] = '6';
                break;
            case 'e':
                input[i] = '3';
                break;
            case 'i':
                input[i] = '1';
                break;
            case 'o':
                input[i] = '0';
                break;
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

For the input

```
testinput
```

this program has the following output:

```
t3st1nput
```

Answer (score 2):

This function declaration

```
char replace(string input);
```

is incorrect because the function having the return type `char` tries to return a single character.

This function declaration

```
string replace(string input);
```

is correct. However the function implementation is wrong.

For starters you declared a variable length array of the type `string`

```
string s[n+1];
```

where the name `string` denotes an alias for the type `char *`. Instead of an array of pointers  you should declare at least a character array like

```
char s[n+1];
```

However you may not return an array with automatic storage duration from a function.  It will not be alive after exiting the function.

Secondly, you are returning only the last pointer of the array

```
return s[n];
```

that was not even initialized and has an indeterminate value.

Also this statement

```
s[n+1] = "\0";
```

writes outside the array. because the valid range of indices for the declared array is `[0, n + 1)`.

And in statements like that

```
s[i] = "6" ;
```

you are trying to assign pointers to string literals instead of forming a character array.

If you need to replace characters in a character array then there is no need to create a new character array. Just write

```
string replace( string input )
{
    for ( string s = input; *s != '\0'; ++s )
    {
        switch ( *s )
        {
            case 'a':
                *s = '6';
                break;

            case 'e':
                *s = '3';
                break;

            case 'i':
                *s = '1';
                break;

            case 'o':
                *s = '0';
                break;
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

If you want to use the subscript operator then the function can look the following way

```
string replace( string input )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        switch ( input[i] )
        {
            case 'a':
                input[i] = '6';
                break;

            case 'e':
                input[i] = '3';
                break;

            case 'i':
                input[i] = '1';
                break;

            case 'o':
                input[i] = '0';
                break;
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

As you can see there is no need to use the function `strlen`.

But in any case bear in mind that the return type of the function `strlen` is the unsigned integer type `size_t` that usually is declared as an alias for the type `unsigned long`. So not use the signed type `int`. And you should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.  So the variable `n` which is used within the for loop in your function should be declared in the for statement at least like

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( input); i < n; i++)
```

Pay attention to that the letter `'u'` is also a vowel. However it is not processed in your function.

If you need to replace also upper case vowels then rewrite the case labels like for example

```
case 'a': case 'A':
    *s = '6';
    break;
    //...
```

or

```
case 'a': 
case 'A':
    *s = '6';
    break;
    //...
```

Comment: @ikegami It is unclear whether he needs to replace also upper case vowels.

Comment: Pointers are only taught in [week 4 of the CS50 course](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/weeks/4/). However, this exercise is from week 2 of the CS50 course. Therefore, I'm afraid that OP won't be able to understand your solution which uses a pointer, because OP probably has not learnt that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We haven´t seen pointers yet so I´ll have to come back to this solution when it´s clearer for me - slowly getting there ;)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You are right. I used the variable n because in the original code there is used the function strlen. I have updated the code.