# passing argument 1 of 'strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, pointers, integer, parameter-passing, strcat

I am trying to get 10 random numbers and collect them in a char array to get a random customer ID
But it's giving this warning. I couldn't fix it whatever I do. Can you help?

```
char customerid(){
    char id[100];
    char b[50];
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        int n = rand() % 10;
        char c = n + 48;
        strcat(id, c); //here is the problem
        
    }
    printf("%s", id[100]);





    return id[100];
}
```

Here is my second trial:

```
char customerid(){
char id[100];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    int n = rand() % 10;
    char* c = (char*)n + '0';
    strcat(id, c);
    
}
printf("%s", id[100]);





return id[100];
```

}
But it still gives the same error. Can you correct the code? How do we add an integer or char to a string array?

Comment: There is no `strcpy` in your code, only `strcat`. The *second* parameter of that should be a string (array of `char`) but you only pass a single `char`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `strcat` concatenates 2 strings. Not 1 string and 1 single character. A `char` is an integer type which is why your compiler mentions "from integer" in the error message

Comment: `printf("%s", id[100]);` and `return id[100];` are both incorrect as well. You should generally call `srand(time(0));` once at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Not an error but bad style: Do not use magic numbers. If you mean `'0'` then use `'0'` instead of `48`. Besides improving readability, would also be correct if your system would use another encoding than ASCII (but that is very unlikely to happen these days)

Comment: You'll also want to read [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c).

Comment: Please do not repeat identical text. Instead try to add more useful information to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically done wrong everything that can be done wrong.

- you cannot return arrays in C. You need to pass the pointer to the array to the function and fill that array from within the function
- `strcat` is the wrong function, you don't want to concat two strings, instead you want to construct a string character by character.
- `char customerid(...` is pointless, it returns a single character which is not what you want.
- `printf("%s", id[100]);` prints element 100 (which by the way doesn't exist, because you array has only 100 elements and array index start at 0).
- calling `srand` each and every time doesn't make sense. Read this SO article for an explanation: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once). BTW, for debugging purposes it can be useful not to call `srand` at all, then you will always get the same sequence of random numbers.

You probably want this:

```
void customerid(char *id) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    id[i] = rand() % 10 + '0';
  }
  id[i] = 0;   // put the null string terminator
}

int main()
{
  srand(time(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  // generate 10 different ids
  {
    char id[100];        // id will contain the random customer id
    customerid(id);      // call customerid and tell it to fill the id array
    printf("%s\n", id);  // print the customer id
  }
}
```

I suggest you read the chapter dealing with pointers, the one dealing with strings and the one dealing with arrays in your C text book.

Comment: "You've basically done wrong everything that can be done wrong." Hold my beer... :)

Comment: Might also want to add a note about why placing srand inside the function was wrong. The usual duplicate for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once