# C++ reference wrongly received in main()

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)

I am not able to pass the reference properly in the following code.

```
myint& myint::abs()
{
  myint i=*this;
  myint &t=i;
  t.setsign(0);
  return t;      
}
```

The reference 't' is correctly modified in the abs() function. I have printed it and found that its correct. However the value received in main() is always wrong.

I have used the following statement in main()

```
myint a("-12"); /*gives a=-12 with each digit in a linked list node. separate data field for sign.*/
myint b=a.abs();
```

b received is 0, the default value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Returning reference to a local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a nicely written question (thank you), but it is one that has been asked before with only the most trivial differences.  As such, it is likely to be closed shortly.  You can see a number of good answers to your question already by following the link given by @DCoder.

Comment: Re: "The reference 't' is correctly modified" -- the code does not modify the reference `t`. It modifies the `int` that `t` is a reference to. References can not be modified (absent perversion).

Comment: Hi DCoder, Thanks for the reply. I had seen this question but didnt think it was useful. However, having gone through it again, I think I know what I am missing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a reference to a local variable 'i'.
i has gone out of scope when you return from the function so using the reference to it causes undefined behavior.