# Use of array subscription operator

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I have a class `complex` and class `signal` defined.
I have overloaded + and - for complex class.
signal class is defined with a member of complex type `complex *sig_Data;` and i have used array subscription for signal as follows

```
complex &operator[](int i)
    {
        if(i >= range_start && i <= range_end) return sig_Data[zero_pt+i];
        else return complex(0);
    }
```

`zero_pt` is used as a reference.

for the operator overloading of + for signal class I have used this

```
signal operator+(signal &a, signal &b)
{
    int r_start = min(a.range_start, b.range_start);
    int r_end = max(a.range_end, b.range_end);
    int z_pt = max(a.zero_pt, b.zero_pt);
    signal temp(r_start, r_end, z_pt);
    for(int i = r_start; i <= r_end; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

the addition seems to happen correctly here when i checked the values using VC++ in debug but they are not being assigned to temp.
I even tried using an assignment overload with the copy-swap idiom ([What is the copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)).

The constructor used in the `signal operator[](int i)` function is.

```
signal(int r_start, int r_end, int z_pt)
    {
        range_start = r_start;
        range_end = r_end;
        zero_pt = z_pt;
        int arr_ind = r_end - r_start;

        sig_Data = new complex [arr_ind];
    }
```

Please help me identify where I'm going wrong.

A more complete code:

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string>

    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <cstring>


    using namespace std;


    namespace Complex
    {
        class complex
        {
            double real;
            double imag;

        public:
            complex(double re = 0, double im = 0)
            {
                real = re;
                imag = im;
            }

            complex(complex &t)
            {
                real = t.real;
                imag = t.imag;
            }

            void StrtoComplex(const char *temp)
            {
                int i;

                for(i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
                {
                    if(temp[i] == 'j' || temp[i] == 'i')
                        break;
                }

                real = atof(temp);//takes till the last valid char so after + or whitespace it ignores
                if(*(temp + i - 1) == '-')
                    imag = -atof(temp + i + 1);
                else
                    imag = atof(temp + i + 1);

            }

            friend complex operator+(complex &a, complex &b);
                    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, complex &t);
            friend istream &operator>>(istream &s, complex &t);
            };
        //overloading + to add complex numbers
        complex operator +(complex &a, complex &b)
        {
            complex t;
            t.real = a.real + b.real;
            t.imag = a.imag + b.imag;
            return(t);
        }

        ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, complex &t)
        {
            s<<t.real<<" +j"<<t.imag;
            return s;
        }

        istream &operator>>(istream &s, complex &t)
        {
            std::string temp;

            std::getline(s, temp);
            t.StrtoComplex(temp.c_str());
            return s;
        }
    }

    namespace Discrete
    {
        using Complex::complex;
        class signal
        {
            complex *sig_Data;

            int range_start, range_end, zero_pt;

        public:
            signal()
            {
                sig_Data = NULL;
                range_start = range_end = zero_pt = 0;
            }

            signal(complex i)
            {
                sig_Data = new complex(i);
                range_start = range_end = zero_pt = 0;
            }

            signal(int r_start, int r_end, int z_pt)
            {
                range_start = r_start;
                range_end = r_end;
                zero_pt = z_pt;
                int arr_ind = r_end - r_start;

                sig_Data = new complex [arr_ind];
            }

            void StrtoSig(char *temp)
            {
                int arr_ind = 0;
                char *tok;

                if(!*temp) return;

                tok = temp;
                zero_pt = 0;
                //
                int flag;

                for(int i = 0; i < (flag = strlen(temp)); i++)
                {
                    tok++;
                    if(*tok == '^') zero_pt = arr_ind;
                    if(*tok == ',') arr_ind++;
                }
                range_start = 0 - zero_pt;
                range_end = arr_ind - zero_pt;

                sig_Data = new complex [arr_ind];
                tok = temp+1;
                for(int i = 0; i <= arr_ind; i++)
                {
                    if(*tok == ',') tok++;
                    while(isspace(*tok)) tok++;
                    if(*tok == '^') tok++;
                    sig_Data[i].StrtoComplex(tok);
                    while(*tok != ',' && *tok != '}'&& *tok != '\0') tok++;
                }
            }

            complex &operator[](int i)
            {
                if(i >= range_start && i <= range_end) return sig_Data[zero_pt+i];
                //else return complex(0);
            }


            friend signal operator+(signal &a, signal &b);
                    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, signal &t);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &s, signal &t);
        };

        //Overloading + operator
        signal operator+(signal &a, signal &b)
        {
            int r_start = min(a.range_start, b.range_start);
            int r_end = max(a.range_end, b.range_end);
            int z_pt = max(a.zero_pt, b.zero_pt);
            signal temp(r_start, r_end, z_pt);
            for(int i = r_start; i <= r_end; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            }
            return temp;
        }


            ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, signal &t)
{
    s<<"{";
    for(int i = t.range_start; i <= t.range_end; i++)
    {
        if(i == (t.range_start + t.zero_pt))
            s<<" ^"<<t[i];
        else if(i == t.range_end)
            s<<" "<<t[i];
        else
            s<<" "<<t[i]<<",";
    }
    s<<"}";
    return s;
}

        istream &operator>>(istream &s, signal &t)
        {
            char *ip;
            s>>ip;
            t.StrtoSig(ip);
            return s;
        }
    }

   void main()
{
    using Discrete::signal;
    signal a,b,c;
    a.StrtoSig("{1+i5, ^7+i6}");
    b.StrtoSig("{5+i4, 7+i5}");

    c = a+b;
    cout<<c;
}
```

Comment: In your subscription function, you return complex(0) when index is out of bounds. How will you then differentiate between a zero element and incorrect indexing ?

Comment: returning reference to temporaty object `temp` is asking for troubles. `operator+` should return a copy.

Comment: @AshRj It does not matter really because I'm assuming the value of the signal out of this bound is zero....

Comment: Your `signal::operator[]` is returning a local by reference in the case `i` is outside of the range. Don't do that. And similarly for `complex::operator+`.

Comment: @aleguana I'll consider ur suggestion but the temp is not being assigned even b4 being returned

Comment: Ok i changed them but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: and if fixing that doesn't solve your issue, please post the implementation of the `signal` constructor used by `complex::operator+`.

Comment: the way you changed the code made it worse ... your `signal::operator[]` has to return by reference in order to allow modifying the actual contents. You just can't return a reference to a local.

Comment: @PSK, well it looks like you didn't even try to compile with these modifications. Now your `operator[]` returns a copy which shouldn't compile because it's not an lvalue and `temp[i] = a[i] + b[i]` is illegal

Comment: Also the way you check the range in `operator[]` seems wrong; it should be `if(i >= range_start && i < range_end)`, or if you really want both `range_start` and `range_end` to be valid indices you should use `int arr_ind = r_end - r_start + 1;` in the `signal` constructor.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker I don't understand what you mean by reference to a local ..are you referring to the `return complex(0)` part?

Comment: @aleguna It compliled fine with the above changes i made...PS: I didn't understand a word of the rest you said

Comment: @PSK : yes, that's what I'm referring to. The subject of returning references to locals has been addressed before on SO, eg. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Ok say my index is not out of this range defined then shouldn't the above code work fine (as it is compling fine in VC++ im assuming its not a syntax or compiler error)

Comment: several other issues have been pointed out that need to be fixed too. But in order to track down the root cause of your issue, you'll need to post a more complete (compilable) code sample that has the behavior you observe.

Comment: please include a `main` in the code to show how you use these classes.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I would love to but my program runs some 600+ lines ...if you still want me to I can ... wasn't too sure if you would want to read through all that code

Comment: just a simple example of adding two signals will do. It doesn't have to be your complete code - just a small (compilable) subset of it that has the behavior you're trying to fix. Leave out everything that is not relevant to the problem, while keeping just enough to show what's going wrong.

Comment: @PSK, don't get rediculous none is going to read all the code you just posted. just give an example of two `signal` objects that cause the problem

Comment: Ok added a simpler version ...

Comment: Whats is the outcome of `StrtoSig` in this case? That's all we need to know, unless you want us to debug your parsing as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to modify the class through the `operator[]`, it must return a reference:

```
complex &operator[](int i)
{
    if(i >= range_start && i <= range_end) return sig_Data[zero_pt+i];
    else throw std::range_error("invalid index to operator[]");
}
```

When you return a value, it's being copied into a temporary, so assignment to the result of `operator[]` gets discarded at the end of the expression.

Comment: ...i did this but didn't help. Besides someone just suggested me here not to use reference..

Comment: @PSK that was about `operator+`, which should return by value, not by reference.  `operator[]` should return by reference.

Comment: @PSK : we didn't say not to return by reference ... we said not to return *locals* by reference. There's a difference ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, let me mentally debug your code for you

imagine that you've got two signals

```
signal s1 (5, 20, 8);
signal s2 (3, 25, 9);
```

now you are trying to add then

```
signal s = s1 + s2;
```

What happens is this:

1. You construct a `temp` signal:

   signal temp (3, 25, 9);
2. Which creates an internal array

   sig_Data = new complex [22];
3. Your loop look like this

   for (i = 3; i < 25; ++i)
4. For every `i` your `operator[]` does this

   if(i >= range_start && i <= range_end) return sig_Data[9+i];
5. Now imagine a step where `i = 15`, it will do this

   return sig_Data[9+15];

Which breaches array boundaries which is undefined behavour.

Now, I'll leave it to you to fix this mess.

PS
Besies, you have a memory leak, you never `delete[] sig_Data`. And even if you did you would have got a heap corruption becuase you do a shallow copy in your copy constructor

Comment: I guess this is my fault but your understanding of my code is wrong... My `range_start` is never greater then zero and my `zero_pt` is simply the count make the range shift with respect to zero ... I'll add tht code in a bit as well

Comment: @PSK, give an example of two signals your are trying to add which reproduce the problem