# C++ Program abruptly ends after cin

Tags: c++

I am writing code to get the last digit of very large fibonacci numbers such as fib(239), etc.. I am using strings to store the numbers, grabbing the individual chars from end to beginning and then converting them to int and than storing the values back into another string. I have not been able to test what I have written because my program keeps abruptly closing after the `std::cin >> n;` line. 
Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using namespace std; 

char get_fibonacci_last_digit_naive(int n) {
cout << "in func";
if (n <= 1)
    return (char)n;

string previous= "0";
string current= "1";

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    //long long tmp_previous = previous;
    string tmp_previous= previous; 

    previous = current;

    //current = tmp_previous + current; // could also use previous instead of current
    // for with the current length of the longest of the two strings
    //iterates from the end of the string to the front
    for (int j=current.length(); j>=0; --j) {
        // grab consectutive positions in the strings & convert them to integers
        int t;
        if (tmp_previous.at(j) == '\0') 
            // tmp_previous is empty use 0 instead
            t=0;  
        else
            t = stoi((string&)(tmp_previous.at(j))); 
        int c = stoi((string&)(current.at(j)));
        // add the integers together
        int valueAtJ= t+c;
        // store the value into the equivalent position in current
        current.at(j) = (char)(valueAtJ); 
    }
    cout << current << ":current value"; 
}

return current[current.length()-1];
}

int main() {
int n;
std::cin >> n;

//char& c = get_fibonacci_last_digit_naive(n);  // reference to a local variable returned WARNING
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable
cout << "before call";
char c = get_fibonacci_last_digit_naive(n);
std::cout << c << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

The output is consistently the same. No matter what I enter for n, the output is always the same. This is the line I used to run the code and its output.

```
$ g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++14 fibonacci_last_digit.cpp -lm

$ ./a.exe
10
```

There is a newline after the 10 and the 10 is what I input for n. 
I appreciate any help. And happy holidays!

Comment: Try compiling with the `-g` flag and debugging with `gdb`.

Comment: I checked and I dont have gdb. So Ill have to install it.

Comment: It's worthwhile to get. It helps a lot.

Comment: Here's what I get from running your code:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
before callin funcAbort trap: 6

Comment: You are doing it all totally wrong. Intricacies of the C++ language aside, in order to know that the last digit of 17795+23417 is 2, you don't need to calculate the sum of 17795 and 23417. You don't even need to *remenber* 17795 and 23417. All you need to have is 5 and 7.

Comment: I concur with @n.m. The algorithm should be simply to calculate the next value as `value = current + previous`, then `previous  = current`, then `current = value % 10`, using nothing but unsigned integer types (any, really). The value of `current` after the last iteration will be the digit you seek.

Comment: Regarding your use of C++, you need to understand two things: (1) type casting is you telling the compiler to shut up because you know better; and (2) you don't know better. Thus, don't use type casts at this stage of your programming career. They are a waste of your time. In particular, your usage of `(string&)(tmp_previous.at(j))` etc. is undefined behaviour and makes no sense however you look at it.

Comment: @noc_coder You didn't flush `cout << "before call";` - misleads your diagnostics.

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand what you guys are saying but when I had it that way, the numbers were overflowing. Even with long long as the type.

Comment: @noc_coder Then you evidently missed the modulo that is so important to the algorithm I described. The algorithm should simply be [something like this example](http://ideone.com/EA7M8F), which prints the last digit of fib(0...299). No actual value calculation will ever exceed `18`. You could literally do this with 5-bit values.

Comment: @n.m I am just failing to see how I can get the 5 and 7 without previously having calculated the number with the 5 and the number with the 7...

Comment: Regarding your attempt at long addition, you forgot the carry. It's this little thing that makes numbers grow longer and longer. 99+1= 100. Your method fails to take this into account. Your strings never grow in length.

Comment: @n.m .. Thats true...

Comment: @WhozCraig I see this example you posted, the modulus makes sense now... Thanks..

Comment: "how I can get the 5" By adding up last digits of two other numbers, and discarding the carry.

Comment: @n.m Why is there a difference with using unsigned vs signed as the type of int? http://ideone.com/EA7M8F

Comment: @noc_coder for this example, there is no difference. However, in practice, there is no reason on earth to tote around a sign bit when you don't actually ever need one, and remedial fibonacci numbers don't.

Comment: By the way you may want to read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm posting this because your understanding of the problem seems to be taking a backseat to the choice of solution you're attempting to deploy. This is an example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), a problem where the choice of solution *method* and problems or roadblocks with its implementation obfuscates the actual problem you're trying to solve.

You are trying to calculate the final digit of the Nth [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), where N could be gregarious. The basic understanding of the fibonacci sequence tells you that

> ```
> fib(0) = 0 
> fib(1) = 1 
> fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2), for all n larger than 1.
> ```

The iterative solution to solving `fib(N)` for its *value* would be:

```
unsigned fib(unsigned n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;

    unsigned previous = 0;
    unsigned current = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    {
        unsigned value = previous + current;
        previous = current;
        current = value;
    }
    return current;
}
```

which is all well and good, but will obviously overflow once `N` causes an overflow of the storage capabilities of our chosen data type (in the above case, `unsigned` on most 32bit platforms will overflow after a mere 47 iterations).

But we don't *need* the actual `fib` values for each iteration. We only need the last digit of each iteration. Well, the base-10 last-digit is easy enough to get from any unsigned value. For our example, simply replace this:

```
current = value;
```

with this:

```
current = value % 10;
```

giving us a near-identical algorithm, but one that only "remembers" the last digit on each iteration:

```
unsigned fib_last_digit(unsigned n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;

    unsigned previous = 0;
    unsigned current = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    {
        unsigned value = previous + current;
        previous = current;
        current = value % 10; // HERE
    }
    return current;
}
```

Now `current` always holds the single last digit of the prior sum, whether that prior sum exceeded 10 or not really isn't relevant to us. Once we have that the next iteration can use it to calculate the sum of two single positive digits, which cannot exceed 18, and again, we only need the last digit *from that* for the *next* iteration, etc.. This continues until we iterate however many times requested, and when finished, the final answer will present itself.

**Validation**

We know the first 20 or so fibonacci numbers look like this, run through `fib`:

```
0:0
1:1
2:1
3:2
4:3
5:5
6:8
7:13
8:21
9:34
10:55
11:89
12:144
13:233
14:377
15:610
16:987
17:1597
18:2584
19:4181
20:6765
```

Here's what we get when we run the algorithm through `fib_last_digit` instead:

```
0:0
1:1
2:1
3:2
4:3
5:5
6:8
7:3
8:1
9:4
10:5
11:9
12:4
13:3
14:7
15:0
16:7
17:7
18:4
19:1
20:5
```

That should give you a budding sense of confidence this is likely the algorithm you seek, and you can forego the string manipulations entirely.

Comment: @noc_coder Glad it helped. Best of luck. Sometimes when you really run into stiff roadblocks when trying to implement a solution you need to separate yourself from that effort and rethink what the actual problem is you're solving. It happens a LOT in this line of work, so don't think poorly of yourself. Just try to recognize it, remember what you can from prior work (it may come in handy someday), and rethink the real problem again.

Answer (score 1):

Running this code on a Mac I get:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string before callin funcAbort trap: 6
```

The most obvious problem with the code itself is in the following line:

```
for (int j=current.length(); j>=0; --j) {
```

Reasons:

1. If you are doing things like current.at(j), this will crash immediately. For example, the string "blah" has length 4, but there is no character at position 4.
2. The length of tmp_previous may be different from current. Calling tmp_previous.at(j) will crash when you go from 8 to 13 for example.

Additionally, as others have pointed out, if the the only thing you're interested in is the last digit, you do not need to go through the trouble of looping through every digit of every number. The trick here is to only remember the last digit of previous and current, so large numbers are never a problem and you don't have to do things like stoi.

Comment: I see now and dont doubt that these are issues. But would this issue also be the cause of why "before call" and "in func" were not even printed? Im going to use the gdb to test myself too.

Comment: Yes, because most of the time cout will hold stuff in a buffer instead of writing its contents immediately. Try replacing that line with `cout << "before call" << flush`;

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a previous answer would be the string addition.
I tested it with the fibonacci number of 100000 and it works fine in just a few seconds. Working only with the last digit solves your problem for even larger numbers for sure. for all of you requiring the fibonacci number as well, here an algorithm:

```
std::string str_add(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    // http://ideone.com/o7wLTt

    size_t n = max(a.size(), b.size());
    if (n > a.size()) {
        a = string(n-a.size(), '0') + a;
    }

    if (n > b.size()) {
        b = string(n-b.size(), '0') + b;
    }

    string result(n + 1, '0');

    char carry = 0;

    std::transform(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), b.rbegin(), result.rbegin(), [&carry](char x,  char y)
    {
        char z = (x - '0') + (y - '0') + carry;
        if (z > 9) {
            carry = 1;
            z -= 10;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
        return z + '0';
    });

    result[0] = carry + '0';

    n = result.find_first_not_of("0");
    if (n != string::npos) {
        result = result.substr(n);
    }

    return result;
}

std::string str_fib(size_t i)
{
    std::string n1 = "0";
    std::string n2 = "1";
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < i; ++idx) {
        const std::string f = str_add(n1, n2);
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = f;
    }
    return n1;
}

int main() {
    const size_t i = 100000;
    const std::string f = str_fib(i);
    if (!f.empty()) {
        std::cout << "fibonacci of " << i << " = " << f << " | last digit: " << f[f.size() - 1] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.sync(); std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with first calculating the fibonacci number and then converting the `int` to a `std::string` using `std::to_string()`. in the following you can extract the last digit using the `[]` operator on the last index.

```
int fib(int i)
{
    int number = 1;
    if (i > 2) {
        number = fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2);
    }
    return number;
}

int main() {
    const int i = 10;
    const int f = fib(i);
    const std::string s = std::to_string(f);

    if (!s.empty()) {
        std::cout << "fibonacci of " << i << " = " << f << " | last digit: " << s[s.size() - 1] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.sync(); std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Avoid duplicates of the using keyword `using`.

Also consider switching from `int` to `long` or `long long` when your numbers get bigger. Since the fibonacci numbers are positive, also use `unsigned`.

Comment: This fib function wont work. That was the last one I did. The idea is to be able to handle extremely large fib numbers like fib(300). Thats why I choose to use strings.

Comment: so you basically want a manual string addition. try to encapsulte this function fist: `std::string add(std::string a, std::string b)`

Comment: then change from all `int` to `std:.string` in the `fib()` function?

Comment: Yes, Ill continue doing it like that just to finish it out. With the add function too. Thanks for the suggestion. I think due to runtime requests of the test cases, I might have to go the modulus route.

Comment: The problem states very large values of fib, so long long does not really address the issue. @JKreiser your fib function should only return the last digit because that's the only thing we care about.