# Function returning reference to local variable

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
int & foo () {
    int b = 2;
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int a = foo();
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

Foo returns reference to variable `b`, which is out of scope of main. The cout prints 2. Does this mean that a copy of `b` is created? Or is it that lifetime of `b` is extended to the lifetime of `a`?

Comment: Because C++ won't stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. You need to know what you are doing. Yes, it isn't safe, but oh so powerful.

Comment: has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable

Comment: You may find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)

Comment: @Ap31 I disagree, I have already read that. What the answer there says is "will not work because you're returning an alias (a reference) to an object with a lifetime limited to the scope of the function call". However, it works, and I am asking how..

Comment: @Mykybo Undefined Behaviour means that sometimes things can appear to work, but this is by chance only.  In this case the returned reference is referencing a position in the stack that no longer contains valid data, it is just chance that the value at this position has not yet been overwritten.

Comment: @Mykybo well I guess the answer might be clearer on the part of what "will not work" means. And it means UB, which could result in any behavior, including what you observe.