# Cascading Function Calls

Tags: c++

Using a function that looks like:

```
IntegerSet &insert(int m);
```

I'm trying to create a function that supports cascading calls that insert values into an object's array.

My function:

```
IntegerSet &IntegerSet::insert(int m) {
    IntegerSet newObj;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        newObj.set1[i] = set1[i]; //copy the array into the new object
    }
    newObj.set1[m] = true;
    return newObj;
}
```

The object being returned is empty, which I suspect has to do with the reference.

Attempting to change it by altering the `&` to look like

```
IntegerSet IntegerSet::&insert(int m)
```

makes it refuse to compile because it 'expects an identifier'.

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local variable. Perhaps you might expand your example to include the definition for IntegerSet and how you're actually using it.  You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you intended in order to make fluent syntax work:

```
IntegerSet& IntegerSet::insert(int m)
{
    this->set1[m] = true;
    return *this;
}
```

For fluent syntax, you typically want a lot of member functions called on the same object, not proliferation of temporary objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return a reference to a local, as it will have been destroyed by the time the function returns. However, you probably want to modify the `IntegerSet` on which you call `insert` instead and return a reference to `*this`. This is much more efficient than making a copy each time.

```
IntegerSet &IntegerSet::insert(int m) {
    set1[m] = true;
    return *this;
}
```

This way you can chain function calls on an `IntegerSet` object like so:

```
iset.insert(1).insert(2).insert(3);
```