# Why return local variable with reference type works in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm so confused in below code which is worked in VS2012 Update 5 but failed in g++ 8.1.

```
int& func()
{
    int i = 0;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int ri = func();
    ri++;
    std::cout << ri << std::endl; // output "1"
    return 0;
}
```

Per I understand and refer to the similar question [C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable), it should be failed because the lifetime of the local variable `i` in function `func` should be ended after the function call.

But, **why it is worked in VS2012?**

[image: running in VS2012]

*Failed in g++ 8.1.1*
[image: g++ build with warning]

[image]

It makes me have no sleep.

**Updated v1**:
Add VS2012 specified version and change code to use variable `ri`.

Comment: UB means anything is possible.

Comment: By "worked", you mean "the compiler did not complain". Those aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Steve "worked" mean the compiler has no warning or error, and running is ok without crash.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: That compiler simply does not recognize this problem (it would seem).

Comment: "undefined behavior - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program. Examples of undefined behavior are memory accesses outside of array bounds, signed integer overflow, null pointer dereference, modification of the same scalar more than once in an expression without sequence points, access to an object through a pointer of a different type, etc. **Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior (although many simple situations are diagnosed), and the compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful.**" (emphasis added)

Comment: @Leo -- *"worked" mean the compiler has no warning or error, and running is ok without crash*  -- If you have your driver's license taken away from you, does that stop you from getting into a car and driving it, even though it is illegal for you to do so?   Maybe you get stopped by a policeman right away, maybe you drive thousands of miles without any issues, etc.  That's how you should think of this situation.

Comment: By the way, the fact that the program probably output the correct thing should be considered coincidence. Perhaps that compiler *always* will do that, but if you upgrade or change (as you have seen), the behavior is simply not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, so should I say the "undefined behavior" is depended the implementation in different compiler and platform? If so, then in VS environment it worked, right?

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) has a good explanation, I'm not consider this searching. But, why this one should be treated a down vote?

Comment: The discrepancies in downvotes: Different people on different days. Maybe some of the same people, but someone was in a bad mood today. I've had stuff downvoted for reasons that I'll never understand.

Comment: It only worked in VS by dumb luck. At any point memory that you no longer own can be reallocated for other purposes. Both are stack-based systems, but there's nothing stopping VS from or GCC from ordering things in such a way that `int ri`doesn't wind up being assigned to itself, for example. And there's nothing a small bug fix in VS's compiler or a chance to VS2015 from making the "working" stop. Or start summoning nasal goblins. [Or make your boss look bad at Comdex.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE)

Comment: Not at all. There's a difference between compiler specific stuff and undefined behavior. With compiler specific things, the behavior is guaranteed by the compiler (in other compilers, this may be different, or even be undefined behavior). You may or may not want to use compiler specific things. Anything can happen with undefined behavior, so you never want it in your program.

Comment: Got it, thanks all. I'm a fresher in C++, so per you all's comments, I know I need to treat the different compiler with different specification, especially for UB. However, always follow the good behavior is the basic principle of writing good code. And avoid UB is first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is undefined behavior, this might work randomly as the stack frame is not overwritten with new values and able to access the memory location (which holds garbage). We should never return a reference to the local variable.

Comment: This is an excellent point. The value referenced may change unexpectedly, and changing it could result in other UB (reading should also be considered UB).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this code with [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/11/14/visual-studio-2012-update-4/), [Visual Studio 2013 Update 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/07/20/visual-studio-2013-update-5/), [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3/), and Visual Studio 2017 ([15.7 update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2018/05/07/vs-2017-15-7-update/)).

At normal warnings (`/W3`) all four resulted in:

> warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: i

Maybe you just have the warning level too low? (`/W0` or `/W1`).

As to why it works at all, it's probably because you immediately turn the reference into a value type, so you never actually try to use the address for anything interesting. As noted by other's, this is officially "Undefined behavior" as far as the C++ language is concerned.

```
int ri = func();
```

Comment: I also tried to use the variable `ri` with `ri++`, and it worked with new value 1 for `ri`

Comment: I'm using VS2012 Update 5 and the warning level is `/W3`

Comment: Well, I can't try Update 5 since it's not on the downloads page anymore, but there's something in your setup that is suppression the warning C4172 because it is there in Visual C++.

Comment: I have tried to change the warning level to `/W4`, it showed the warning.