# Returning a variable about to be destroyed in a function

Tags: c++

j is destroyed when the function calls return

k is destroyed at the end of the enclosing brackets

If i pass in 9 for j, k is created and will be assigned 81

Returning k will set func1 which is a reference to an integer = k

Returning will immediately terminate the function

My question is, are k and j terminated at the return statement?

If they are func1 should reference nothing...

But i have tried to run this code and it works...

```
int& func1(int j){
 int k = j*j;
 return(k);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)

Comment: "_But i have tried to run this code and it works..._" "It works" is only one of (many) possible manifestations of undefined behavior. It may even continue to work, up until the point you decide to show your code to a potential client, when it might decide to stop working.

Comment: This should also trigger a warning from the compiler depending on your compiler and warning level.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius OMG you are so smart, can we be friends??

Comment: What is the reason for it continuing to work, compiler had a memory lapse?

Comment: @Jokaaa "_What is the reason for it continuing to work, compiler had a memory lapse?_" Compiler's memory had nothing to do with it, since the code is, typically, compiled once, and ran multiple times. It is stated, in C++ standard, that such code would invoke undefined behavior, hence, compiler can compile such code, in whatever way it needs, at the moment of compilation.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius What is the reason that it works the first time and not for any other times after that? There must be something happening with the compiler stage

Comment: @Jokaaa As I already mentioned: short answer: undefined behavior is undefined. There's no point in reasoning about it. Slightly longer answers: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 1):

> and it works...

No, it *appears* to work. The moment you try to access the reference returned by `func1` you enter the Undefined Behavior realm. At that point all bets are off, it could've printed out 42, printed out nothing, crash, eat your CMOS battery etc.

Comment: Nice name, how do you come up with it

Answer (score 0):

> If they are func1 should reference nothing...

You are correct. Try using the reference some more time and you will see:

```
#include <iostream>

int& func1(int j) {
    int k = j * j;
    return(k);
}

int main() {
    int& addr = func1(9);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << addr << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
81
2758456
2758456
2758456
2758456
2758456
2758456
2758456
2758456
2758456
```