# Why does this function in C++ work, but only if printed to stdout?

Tags: c++, reference, printf, cout, dereference

I'm trying to understand how references/pointers/dereferencing works in c++. Please see below for some example code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int& plusThree(int num)
{
    int threeMore = num + 3;
    //std::cout << "threeMore is " << threeMore << "\n";
    //printf("threeMore is %d", threeMore);
    return threeMore;
}


int main()
{
    int three = plusThree(0);
    std::cout << "three is " << three << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The function `plusThree()` shouldn't work, and if you run the code, it doesn't. It'll return `three is 0`. However, if you uncomment either of the lines which prints `threeMore`, `main` will now print `three is 3`...

So my questions are as follows:

1. Why does the function `plusThree()` not work? is it because `int&` means it should return an integer reference, but `return threeMore` is returning an int?
2. Why does the function `plusThree()` now work, if one of `std::cout` or `printf` is uncommented?

Thanks!

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Not all invalid code in c++ is required to crash or fail to c compile. There are many types of errors that simply lead to undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen. "Anything" includes "appearing to work as intended".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable

Comment: Change `int& plusThree(int num)` to `int plusThree(int num)`

Comment: there is no guarantee to get a wrong result when you do something wrong.

Comment: The duplicate answers question 1. Question 2 relies on the false assumption that uncommenting the output expressions makes the function work. It doesn't, it only changes how the Undefined Behavior is expressed.

Answer (score 0):

As ***@Retired Ninja*** mentioned, returning a reference to a local variable from a function has undefined behavior...

The `int threeMore;` should be defined outside the function, or it must be returned by value not a reference.

You must change `plusThree`'s implementation, or the `int threeMore;` variable:

```
int threeMore;
```

***Return by reference:***

```
int threeMore = 0;

int& plusThree(int num)
{
    threeMore = num + 3;
    //std::cout << "threeMore is " << threeMore << "\n";
    //printf("threeMore is %d", threeMore);
    return threeMore;
}
```

***Return by value:***

```
int plusThree(int num)
{
    int threeMore = num + 3;
    //std::cout << "threeMore is " << threeMore << "\n";
    //printf("threeMore is %d", threeMore);
    return threeMore;
}
```