# Returning an object in c++ by reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The goal I set to myself is to overload `operator+` (adding class objects). It turns out that this sum can be just interpreted as the sum of two vectors. But when it comes to the method `operator+`, I find it difficult to return the object. I've read similar topics and even try to apply some sugestions but with no success, unfortunatelly. I enclose some of my code.

```
template<class Y>
class myVect {
public:
    myVect(int n = 1);                          
    ~myVect();
    myVect(const myVect& a);                    

    myVect& operator= (const myVect&);
    myVect& operator+ (const myVect&);

    void display(const myVect& a);      

private:
    int size;
    Y* data;
    template<class U> friend class myClass;     
}; 

template<class Y>                               // constructor      
myVect<Y>::myVect(int n) {
    size = n;
    data = new Y[size];
    cout << endl << "Pass the elements" << " " << size << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin >> *(data + i);
    }
}

template <class Y>                             // deconstructor                 
myVect<Y> :: ~myVect() {
    delete[] data;
}



template<class Y>                               // copy constructor
myVect<Y> ::myVect(const myVect & a) {
    size = a.size;
    data = new Y[size];                         

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *(data + i) = *(a.data + i);            
    }
}

template<class Y>                              //ASSIGMENT OPERATOR                                                 
myVect<Y> & myVect<Y> :: operator= (const myVect<Y> & a) {
    if (this != &a) {                                                   
        delete[] data;                                                  
        size = a.size;                                                  
        data = new Y[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            *(data + i) = *(a.data + i);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The method operator+ is a follows:

```
template<class Y>
myVect<Y>& myVect<Y> ::operator+ (const myVect<Y>& a) {
    if (this->size != a.size) {
    cout << endl << "not able to perform that operation - wrong dimensions" << endl;
    }
    else {
        myVect<Y> newObj(this->size);
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++) {
            *(newObj.data + i) = *(this->data + i) + *(a.data + i);
        }
    }
    return newObj;                                                      
}
```

The error I get is 'newObj': identifier not found. I believe it's due to deconstructor. I tried to put the class `myVect` into a new class (encapsulate it) and contruct the return method but it didn't change antything - the type of the error is still the same. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Anyway, if it is the destructor fault, does that mean that `newObj` is deleted before its return?

Comment: `operator+` should return a new instance not a reference

Comment: operator+ (along with most other binary operators) should normally be a free (non-member) function taking two reference parameters and returning a value, not a reference.

Comment: While returning by reference is a problem here (it's not being used correctly, and it generally can't be used for `operator+`) it is not the cause of the problem you are asking about. The question you are asking about is strictly a scope issue.

Comment: To expand on some of the other comments, in general, you should return by reference for operators that modify state, and return by value for operators that are "pure".

Comment: 1) `newObj` is defined in the `else` block, hence you can't "see" it outside of it. 2) Returning reference to a local variable can lead to undefined behavior, upon using the returned reference: [C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable).

Comment: FrançoisAndrieux is right, I was a bit too fast in closing as dupe, nevertheless you should give this a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: @moooeeeep the q was already closed as dupe of that and then reopened, if you read carefully, the specific problem OP is asking about wont be fixed by returning a value

Comment: Function returns reference to a local variable is wrong practice since that variable will not be exist when the function call is done, and then the reference referencing nothing.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I've been learning c++ for a month and sometimes quite simple things make me helpless. It seems like I must study scope of variables.

Comment: @zorro47 Indeed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to this:

```
int foo()
{
    if (true)  // In reality, some meaningful condition
    {
       int x = 4;
    }

    return x;
}
```

The variable is *scoped* to the `if` block. It doesn't exist outside of it.

You'll have to move its declaration out of the conditional, and do whatever else is required to make that work… or `return` from *inside* the condition, and do something else (throw an exception?) otherwise.

For example, given the above demonstration:

```
int foo()
{
    int x = 0; // Or some other value

    if (true)  // In reality, some meaningful condition
    {
       x = 4;
    }

    return x;
}
```

or:

```
int foo()
{
    if (true)  // In reality, some meaningful condition
    {
       int x = 4;
       return x;
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("For some reason I have no value to give you!");
}
```

Your next problem will be that you are trying to return a local variable by reference. You cannot do that. Return it by value instead, [which is anyway idiomatic for what you're doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Answer (score 2):

You've declared your object inside of a block, so it won't exist in the outside scope. This would normally free you up to reuse variable names across different branches; try making a `newObj` inside the `if` part of the statement and watch it *not* throw an error, for example.

Comment: I put ``newObj`` before ``if`` and now it's ok.

Comment: I'm still studying up on return by reference, value, and pointer, so while I've covered the scope issue, you should see @LightnessRacesinOrbit 's answer for more detail on the possible errors this method could have