# function return by reference to a variable have different address

Tags: c++, function, reference

return by reference function is done so that we would refer to the same variable so that we are not creating other variable for the function.
so isn't it the the address of the returned variable and the function should be same.

```
int& add(int& one, int& two){
int c;
c=one+two;
cout<<"address of one is:"<<&c;
return c;
```

the main function

```
int main(){
  int a=10;
  int b=20;
 cout<<"address of add  function is: "<<(void*)&add<<endl;
```

both address are not equal.

Comment: the function and what it returns are two completely different things, how comes you think they should have the same address?

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope. OP doesn't seem to understand the syntax of what he was inferring.

Comment: if you allow a very far fetched analogy, this is similar to asking "Why is the value of + not 3?"

Comment: Not a duplicate (because it's not what you are asking) but read [this question (C++ Returning reference to local variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable). Your `add` function is defective, you cannot return a reference to a local object from a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main

```cpp
cout<<"address of add  function is: "<<(void*)&add<<endl;
```

will show adress in memory of function add.

The function has its memory address.
Not only output of your function, but the function itself.

(void*)&add returns address of function add.

Whats more, you dont even call function add in your main, so you can not compare addresses. You only check its address in virtual memory.

if you change it to

```cpp
cout<<"address of add  function is: "<<(void*)&add(a,b)<<endl;
```

you will see that addresses match

but the address of function, and address of output of function can not be the same address. Those are two different things.
Function can not return value to the address of function address.
It would not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

> `cout<<"address of add  function is: "<<(void*)&add<<endl;`

This line of code will not output the return of function `add`. The expression `(void*)&add` will actually return the address of the *function* `add`, not the return of it - that is it'll return the address of where the *code* of the function `add` is located in memory, not the address of the variable `c`.

Besides that typo, you probably got a warning by compiling this code as you are returning the reference of a local variable in the function `add`. Automatic storage duration variables like `c` should not consider to be allocated and valid anywhere outside of the scope where it is declared.

Comment: why did you use word virtual address not  address of function on stack part of physical memory?

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa because it is the correct term. The `&` operator returns the virtual address of its argument in your example not the address of physical memory.

Comment: It is important to note though that this is not a terminology supported by the C++ standard as it is specific to the operating system. However this is how basically all modern operating system works in this intent.