# Is it safe to return a string object which points to a local char variable

Tags: c++

I believe that the following code is safe to return the string, even though inelegant, and works as expected, but I'd like confirmation of that, and I'd also like a test case to wrap around it that proves it is safe; ie that the contents of the string are available to the caller via .c_str() method, after the stack is re-used: ie, how can I force the stack on which the local variable resides to be freed/re-used (I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and PVS-Studio static code analysis, neither of which generates a warning). I don't like replacing the local szLocalTime with a global, nor do I like the idea of a malloc in the function as that places the onus on the caller to free. I've added some examples of cases that fill in the char[], eg C lib or Win32 functions that don't know about strings.

```
string FormatTimestamp(SYSTEMTIME st)
{
    char szLocalTime[1000];

    szLocalTime[0] = 0;

    // *** Some code that depends on a char buffer fills szLocalTime...
    // eg. strftime(szLocalTime, sizeof(szLocalTime)...);
    // eg. GetDlgItemText(hDlg, ID, szLocalTime, sizeof(szLocalTime));



    string s = szLocalTime; // <-- the question relates to this
    return s;
}
```

Comment: std::strings don't "point" to anything

Comment: Anything named an iterator, view, range or ptr will need to keep the original source around. However, most standard containers make copies and don't need the original.

Comment: Unrelated: Possibly `*** Some code that fills szLocalTime in Here ***` could take advantage of a `std::stringstream` or [Howard Hinnant's Date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to simplify things.

Comment: Are you sure you meant your code like that? Maybe you were actually wondering about [returning a reference to a local var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)? Which in your case would mean changing the function signature to returning a string&.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` always copies its initializer. So it is safe.

Answer (score -1):

As stated by Maxim, `std::string` always makes a copy of whatever it's given, so this is safe to do. If you want to avoid copying, you could also just do this:

```
string FormatTimestamp(SYSTEMTIME st)
{
    std::string szLocalTime(1000, '\0'); 

    // String automatically initialized to 0
    // *** Some code that fills szLocalTime in Here ***

    szLocalTime.resize(strlen(szLocalTime.data())); 
    return szLocalTime; // <-- the question relates to this 
}
```

Comment: `std::string szLocalTime(1000);` won't compile.  You need `std::string szLocalTime(1000, 0);`  which means  `szLocalTime[0] = 0;` is not needed.

Comment: Moreover, with *move semantic* the string is not copied, just moved.

Comment: @BiagioFesta The copying of the characters is avoided by this solution. Move semantics are irrelevant.