# Unexpected out (virtual function returning string)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am having some trouble with an unexpected output in the following simple code. The output works fine with the base class but I run into trouble with the derived class for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class vehicle {
public:
    string* name;
    vehicle() {}
    vehicle(const string& inputName) {name = new string(inputName);} //constructor
    virtual ~vehicle() {delete name; name = nullptr;} // always make base class destructor virtual
    //vehicle(const vehicle& rhs) {*this = rhs; cout << "copy called" << endl;} //copy constructor
    vehicle& operator=(const vehicle& rhs) {
        cout << "assignment called" << endl;
        if(this == &rhs){
            return *this;
        }
        name = new string(*rhs.name);
        return *this;
    } //assignment operator
    virtual string& getName() const {return *name; cout << "base" << endl;} //mark function const if we are not going to make any changes to the object
};

class car : public vehicle {
    string *title = new string;
public:
    car() : vehicle() {}
    car(const string& inputName) : vehicle(inputName) {*title = inputName;}
    virtual ~car() {}
    virtual string& getName() const {string temp = *title; return temp; cout << "derived" << endl;}
};
int main() {

    car test("honda");
    string temp;
    temp = test.getName();
    cout << temp;

    return 0;
}
```

I am intending to get the following output:

```
honda
```

But am getting:

```
~weird square boxes~
```

Edit:

What i'm really trying to accomplish is something like the following in the derived class:

```
virtual string& getName() const {return "Car: " + *name;}
```

Before I get enflamed for using the heap for the string, please know that I am only experimenting here. It is my understanding that this should, in theory, work.

Comment: You're returning a reference to a temporary.  Bad things will happen.

Comment: Why are `name` and `title` pointers?

Comment: `string *title = new string;` drop the `*` and fix all uses of `title` that dereference it. It should not be a pointer

Comment: In general, pointer to `string` is not that useful. In it's most basic form, `string` is a pointer and a count and you gain nothing by adding another pointer into the mix. Dynamically allocating a string is a also a poor move. `string`s job is to take care of the nitty gritty of dynamic allocation for you. If you find yourself with a problem where you need to take managing the allocation back upon yourself, `string` probably isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: C++ is not Java.  Stop using the `new` keyword.

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: @ilikemath3.14 Your edit does nothing to reduce the concerns raised by others. You still have not demonstrated anything that benefits from (much less necessitates) using a dynamically-allocated `string` object. Plus you have demonstrated a greater need for `getName()` to avoid returning a reference to a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)

Comment: @JaMiT The suggestion of not returning by reference suffices. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This function

```
virtual string& getName() const {string temp = *title; return temp; cout << "derived" << endl;}
```

invokes undefined behavior because it returns a reference to a local object temp that will not be alive after exiting the function.

You could define the function like

```
virtual const string& getName() const {return *name;}
```

and

```
const string& getName() const override { return *title;}
```

And the statements after return statements do not have an effect.

Also other your code has drawbacks. For example the copy assignment operator produces a memory leak.

Or you need explicitly to define the destructor for the class car.

Pay attention to that there is no sense to declare data members `name` and `title` as pointers to objects of the type `std::string`. Instead declare data members of the type `std::string`.

Comment: Can you explain why the copy assignment operator produces a memory leak? Explicitly defining the copy constructor for car did not fix the issue:                                           
virtual ~car() {vehicle::~vehicle(); delete title; title = nullptr;}