# C++ make_unique() changing member attributes' values

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr, entity-component-system

I am developing a small game in SDL2 and am in the process of implementing a Quadtree for collision detection in the ECS I have written. The structure of my Quadtree class is similar to [this one](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374) and the full implementation can be found below.

Quadtree.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Box.hpp"

namespace quadtree {
    class Node {
    public:

        Node(int p_level, quadtree::Box<float> p_bounds)
            :level(p_level), bounds(p_bounds) 
        {
            parentWorld = NULL;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                childNodes[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }

        // NOTE: mandatory upon Quadtree initialization
        void setParentWorld(World* p_world_ptr) {
            parentWorld = p_world_ptr;
        }

        void clear() {
            ;
        }

        void split() {
            ;
        }

        int getIndex(Entity* p_ptr_entity) {
            ;
        }

        void insertObject(Entity* p_ptr_entity) {
            ;
        }

        std::vector<Entity*> retrieve(Entity* p_ptr_entity, std::vector<Entity*> returnObjects) {
            ;
        }

        World* getParentWorld() {
            return parentWorld;
        }

    private:
        int MAX_OBJECTS = 10;
        int MAX_DEPTH = 5;
        World* parentWorld;  // used to unpack entities

        int level;  // depth of the node
        quadtree::Box<float> bounds;  // boundary of nodes in the game's map
        std::vector<Entity*> objects;  // list of objects contained in the node: pointers to Entitites in the game
        Node* childNodes[4];

        quadtree::Box<float> getQuadrantBounds(quadtree::Box<float> p_parentBounds, int p_quadrant_id) { ;

        }

    };
}
```

The Quadtree is then passed to a CollisionDetection system class:

DetectCollisions in allSystems.cpp

```
class DetectCollisions : public System {
public:
    DetectCollisions() {
        signature.addComponent<Transform>();
        signature.addComponent<Hitbox>();

        quadtree::Box<float> mapBoundaries = quadtree::Box<float>(0.0f, 0.0f, 1280.0, 736.0);
        quadtree::Node quadtree = quadtree::Node(0, mapBoundaries);
        collisionQuadtree = &quadtree;
    }

    quadtree::Node* getTree() {
        return collisionQuadtree;
    }

    void update(int dt) {
        ;
    }

private:
    quadtree::Node *collisionQuadtree;
};
```

So far there's no problem really: when I check the values of the collisionQuadtree after creating the System all the values are the ones used during initialization of said system. The problem arises when adding this system to the ECS' world using unique pointers:

Main.cpp

```
#include "allSystems.cpp"
#include "world.hpp"

using namespace arcade;

int main() {
    auto entityManager = std::make_unique<EntityManager>();
    auto world = std::make_unique<World>(std::move(entityManager));

    std::unique_ptr<System> keyboard_player_status = std::make_unique<KeyboardPlayerStatus>();
    std::unique_ptr<System> movement = std::make_unique<Movement>();
    std::unique_ptr<System> render = std::make_unique<Render>();
    std::unique_ptr<System> detect_collisions = std::make_unique<DetectCollisions>();  // some attributes of the Quadtree have changed

    DetectCollisions test = DetectCollisions();
    quadtree::Node* test2 = test.getTree();  // attributes are as expected

    world->addSystem(std::move(detect_collisions));
    world->addSystem(std::move(keyboard_player_status));
    world->addSystem(std::move(movement));
    world->addSystem(std::move(render)); 
}
```

All other systems are working well. However, as I've pointed out in the code, creating a unique_ptr of this particular system changes the size of some of the parameters, in contrast with simply creating an instance of the DetectCollision() system. Here's an example using the Debugger in VS:

detect_collision instance (unique pointer, changed values)

[image]

test2 instance (expected values)

[image]

Is it reasonable, then, to deduce that it is std::make_unique() what's causing the variables to change their values? If so, what is a possible workaround? And if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)

Comment: `quadtree` is a local variable in the constructor. You assign this a reference to this object to the `collisionQuadtree` member variable. After the constructor exits any access to this object does result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks so much! Indeed, I added the pointed value as a member attribute in the collision system and that has solved the issue. For some reason I believed that the pointer would still "work" even if the pointed value was deleted, which of course makes no sense at all. If you want you can post this as an answer and I will accept it :)