# Does returning a locally-declared pointer from a function cause it to switch scope?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, lifetime

I know it is good to get in the habit of using the `free()` function to destroy a pointer when you're done with it, but what happens if a pointer is returned from a function? I assume it doesn't send a copy over, because there is no opportunity to destroy it. Does the pointer "switch" scope to the calling function?

Example (useless code, beware):

```
int* getOne(){
    int a = 1, *pA;
    pA = &a;
    return pA;  //what happens to this
}

int main(){
    printf("%i", getOne()); //uses data from the same addresses allocated to pA above?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not a duplicate - a C++ reference and a C pointer are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @juanchopanza sir, this is similar in _concept_, but not a perfect dupe, IMHO. Can you please reconsider it?

Comment: @MarkBessey Maybe this one is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320551/return-pointer-to-data-declared-in-function?rq=1. There are so many of them duplicates, but I think the one used to close this covers it.

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt that there are *lots* of duplicates - this is like the #1 problem for new C users. I just wasn't sure directing people to an answer for a different language would actually be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your code invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as the memory, which the pointer points to, no longer exists. If you want the returned pointer to be valid, you need to allocate memory to it dynamically, which *lives* beyond the function lifetime.

In `C`, you can use [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family to allocated dynamic memory.

FWIW, `free()` doe not destroy a *pointer*. It deallocates the dynamically allocated memory to the pointer, if allocated. Calling free with a non-dynamically allocated pointer, will again result in UB.

Comment: so using `malloc()` will allow it to live past the function's lifetime?

Comment: @jaska yes, for sure. :-)